# How do I keep paragraphs together in HTML columns?

Tags: css, html

So, I have a page that looks like...

```
I am a monkey
I am a monkey too, with
additional information.
I am also a monkey
```

If I wrap this in CSS using the **-webkit-columns:2** tag, it displays as...

```
I am a monkey               additional information
I am a monkey too, with     I am also a monkey
```

I'd like it to avoid splitting the paragraphs in this case.

I'm looking for something like "nobr" or a word-wrap feature or something... eeek. Any ideas?

(Later...) seems I can do this in Firefox, but not Chrome. Hmm...

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for what is called "widow/orphan" control in typography.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742418/widow-orphan-control-with-javascript help?

Comment: Doesn't help too much; it doesn't work for screen.

Comment: What you're talking about is part of the [CSS Multicolumn Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/), specifically in the section [Column breaks](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-breaks). Unfortunately, support for these features seems to be bad at this point. Here's some analysis to that effect: http://zomigi.com/blog/deal-breaker-problems-with-css3-multi-columns/

Comment: Very useful blog post. Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can set

```
p {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

which will prevent that paragraphs from breaking over a column break. May have some other strange effects though so have a good play with it first.

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but I tried this and it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: It worked for `<pre style="(columns...)"> line1; line2; </pre>` situation, where the other "break" soluntion - didn't.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
page-break-inside: avoid;
break-inside: avoid-column;
```

The first should handle Chrome/Safari; the second Firefox. The third is the [standards-compliant](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#break-inside) "correct" way.

H/t https://stackoverflow.com/a/7785711/1431728

Comment: ...you essentially duplcated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26530955/8112776) from a year earlier! (suprising nobody said anything!)

Comment: @ashleedawg, and this one doesn't add any new information that anyone could possibly find helpful?

Answer (score 4):

Although the question is answered, browser support for CSS columns is much better since this this question was first posted. The question is still pretty high in search results and the blog post referenced in the answer is pretty old too. So here's the quick answer: the best way to keep elements from breaking into columns is to use the break-inside property. For example:

```
p {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

For more information, please see [this entry on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/).

Answer (score -1):

What about using a table with invisible borders? Perhaps that may do the trick.

Comment: We're about to forget table-based designs. Embrace semantic web!