# How to prevent column break within an element?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class='x'>
    <ul>
        <li>Number one</li>
        <li>Number two</li>
        <li>Number three</li>
        <li>Number four is a bit longer</li>
        <li>Number five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```css
.x {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    width: 30em;
}
```

As it stands, Firefox currently renders this similarly to the following:

```
• Number one    • Number three          bit longer
• Number two    • Number four is a    • Number five
```

Notice that the fourth item was split between the second and third column. How do I prevent that?

The desired rendering might look something more like:

```
• Number one    • Number four is a
• Number two      bit longer
• Number three  • Number five
```

or

```
• Number one    • Number three        • Number five
• Number two    • Number four is a
                  bit longer
```

**Edit:** The width is only specified to demonstrate the unwanted rendering. In the real case, of course there is no fixed width.

Comment: have you tried to give that li a standalone style?  like <li style="width: ???px">Number four is a bit longer</li>  ???px = needed width to fit that number four.

Answer (score 558, accepted):

The correct way to do this is with the [`break-inside` CSS property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3/#break-within):

```css
.x li {
    break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

Unfortunately, as of October 2021, [this is still not supported in Firefox](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_break-inside_multicol_context_column) but [it is supported by every other major browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside). With Chrome, I was able to use the above code, but I couldn't make anything work for Firefox ([See Bug 549114](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549114)).

The workaround you can do for Firefox if necessary is to wrap your non-breaking content in a table but that is a really, really terrible solution if you can avoid it.

**UPDATE**

According to the bug report mentioned above, Firefox 20+ supports [`page-break-inside: avoid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside) as a mechanism for avoiding column breaks inside an element but the below code snippet demonstrates it still not working with lists:

```css
.x {
    column-count: 3;
    width: 30em;
}

.x ul {
    margin: 0;
}

.x li {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -moz-page-break-inside:avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<div class='x'>
    <ul>
        <li>Number one, one, one, one, one</li>
        <li>Number two, two, two, two, two, two, two, two, two, two, two, two</li>
        <li>Number three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As others mention, you can do `overflow: hidden` or `display: inline-block` but this removes the bullets shown in the original question.  Your solution will vary based on what your goals are.

**UPDATE 2** Since Firefox does prevent breaking on `display:table` and `display:inline-block` a reliable but non-semantic solution would be to wrap each list item in its own list and apply the style rule there:

```css
.x {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    width: 30em;
}

.x ul {
    margin: 0;
    page-break-inside: avoid;           /* Theoretically FF 20+ */
    break-inside: avoid-column;         /* Chrome, Safari, IE 11 */
    display:table;                      /* Actually FF 20+ */
}
```

```html
<div class='x'>
    <ul>
        <li>Number one, one, one, one, one</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Number two, two, two, two, two, two, two, two, two, two, two, two</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Number three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe Opera 11.5 supports `break-inside: avoid-column`

Comment: Looking at [Comment 15](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549114#c15) `page-break-inside:avoid` should work in FF 20.

Comment: Internet Explorer 10 supports `break-inside: avoid-column`.

Comment: At year 2014, the right syntax seems to be:  ```-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;  
-moz-column-break-inside:avoid;  
-o-column-break-inside:avoid;  
-ms-column-break-inside:avoid;  
column-break-inside:avoid;  ```

Comment: @CarlesJoveBuxeda Not seeing any improvement in Firefox 31.  Neither column-break-inside or page-break-inside (with or without prefix) are working.

Comment: Opera doesn't support -o-column-break-inside: avoid; But is does support; -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;

Comment: It's a little late, but as this is still an issue in 2018 this might be useful to others who end up here. If anyone is still having bugs between browsers with this, `overflow: hidden` is the better option. `display: inline-block;` causes new quirks with Chrome, unfortunately.

Comment: I cannot make it work in Chrome and that's exactly what's written on canIuse: `Partial support refers to not supporting the avoid-column, column, and avoid (in the column context) values for the properties break-before, break-after, and break-inside.`

Comment: update: it is broken when an inside container element has relatively big vertical margin. Replacing margin with empty `gutter` element fixed the issue

Comment: Use both avoid and avoid-column. Seems to work across all standard browsers

Comment: @BrianNickel May be time to update this as Firefox v82.0 (out this month) release notes say they added support for this property.

Comment: Tested on **Firefox 97.0.1**, `break-inside: avoid-column;` works perfectly.

Comment: @jona I still see the issue in 97.0.1. `<li style="break-inside: avoid-column">` still breaks.

Comment: Wonderful, this solution resolved me column elements breaking and spreading out over the second column in Safair. Thank you.

Answer (score 213):

Adding;

```
display: inline-block;
```

to the child elements will prevent them being split between columns.

Comment: This is good. A possible way to prevent the bad behavior of inline-block causing stuff to now get squished on one line (if they are too short) is to further wrap this with a `display:block` element. This will likely be a solid Firefox workaround for now.

Comment: This solution removes the list item, so if you're using order lists for example this wouldn't be an alternative.

Comment: Works perfectly for splitting up paragraphs into columns.

Comment: for list items, this can work if you embed the content of the list item (li) within a "span" element set with the "display:inline-block".
The situation is much more complex if you want to control where to break pages or columns within tables : you would like to avoid breaks within table rows (tr).
Really, multi-columns layouts are still difficult to setup, but we need it to allow sites to adapt to very narrow screens (such as smartphones) and to wide displays (where very narrow colulns are really unfair.

Comment: For now the only solution is to create separate pages for several pagewidths, using columns broken manually using tables (and hope that no accesibility option or zoom will change the font sizes!
Developers of browser should really work seriously on multi-columns because smartphones are now spreading, but there are still lot of users wanting to use their wide screens or TV !

Comment: Works for my `<li>` but I had to add `width:100%;` to prevent them from stacking horizontally.

Comment: weird that display:block won't let firefox prevent splitting

Comment: @StevenLu - as at 2020, wrapping this in a `display:block` element now seems to stop this from working in FireFox

Comment: I have two columns, and this (as opposed to `break-inside: avoid-column;`) allowed the child to remain in the first column rather than being moved to the second.

Answer (score 57):

set following to the style of the element that you don't want to break:

```
overflow: hidden; /* fix for Firefox */
break-inside: avoid-column;
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
```

Comment: nice. works for colum text paragraph as well. Added overflow: hidden to the <p> ind the <div> with the columns. Works for FF.

Comment: Actually, the `overflow:hidden` rule is not a fix for the other rules, it *is* what causes the nonbreaking layout…

Answer (score 26):

As of October 2014, break-inside still seems to be buggy in Firefox and IE 10-11. However, adding overflow: hidden to the element, along with the break-inside: avoid, seems to make it work in Firefox and IE 10-11. I am currently using:

```
overflow: hidden; /* Fix for firefox and IE 10-11  */
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
break-inside: avoid-column;
```

Comment: This seems to be the most exhaustive list

Answer (score 16):

Firefox now supports this:

```
page-break-inside: avoid;
```

This solves the problem of elements breaking across columns.

Comment: Have you got this working? I am looking at this fiddle in FF 22 and it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/bnickel/5qwMf/

Comment: Same here, doesn't work in Firefox 22. Also, Firebug only displays `page-break-before:` or `page-break-after:` but not `page-break-inside:`

Comment: Version 28 of Firefox. This is the only one that works for me yet, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This works for me in 2015 :

```css
li {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  /* Firefox */
  break-inside: avoid;
  /* IE 10+ */
}
.x {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  width: 30em;
}
```

```html
<div class='x'>
  <ul>
    <li>Number one</li>
    <li>Number two</li>
    <li>Number three</li>
    <li>Number four is a bit longer</li>
    <li>Number five</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working for me on `ul` elements, is posted on CSS tricks: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/, and seems correct based on caniuse compatibility notes: "Partial support refers to not supporting the `break-before`, `break-after`, `break-inside` properties. WebKit- and Blink-based browsers do have equivalent support for the non-standard `-webkit-column-break-*` properties to accomplish the same result (but only the `auto` and `always` values). Firefox does not support `break-*` but does support the `page-break-*` properties to accomplish the same result."

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is now two years old and things appear to have changed.

[This article](http://trentwalton.com/2012/02/13/css-column-breaks/) explains the use of the `column-break-inside` property.  I can't say how or why this differs from `break-inside`, because only the latter appears to be documented in the W3 spec.  However, the Chrome and Firefox support the following:

```
li {
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
       -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
            column-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for a general <div class="a"> where "a" replaces your "Li" above. The div still broke inside. FF 26

Comment: Not a bug. the code above is correct for the described function even if its selector is just for an li element. You could still use another CSS selector "div.a {...}" instead of "li{...}" in this sample.

Comment: However Chrome still does not support
  -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
on a table row: this does not work and we still cannot avoid breaking tables in bad positions (notably if a tale cell does not just contain text but icons; but Chrome also appears to split at any vertical position in the middle of a text line, breaking the text with the upper part of text glyphs at bottom of the first column, and the lower part of text glyphs at top of the next column !!!
The result is absolutely unreadable !!!

Comment: As of 2017, column-break-inside does not seem to be a valid css property. MDN only says "Edge also supports the non-standard -webkit-column-break-inside variant."

Answer (score 7):

I faced same issue while using card-columns

i fixed it using

```
 display: inline-flex ;
 column-break-inside: avoid;
 width:100%;
```

Comment: Same here. With my `li {display: flex}` multiple elements on 2 columns breaking somewhere in the middle of `li` it helped to change to `li {display: inline-flex}`.

Answer (score 5):

The following code works to prevent column breaks inside elements:

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
-o-column-break-inside: avoid;
-ms-column-break-inside: avoid;
column-break-inside: avoid;
```

Answer (score 4):

Firefox 26 seems to require

```
page-break-inside: avoid;
```

And Chrome 32 needs

```
-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
   -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
        column-break-inside:avoid;
```

Answer (score 4):

In 2019, having this works for me on Chrome, Firefox and Opera (after many other unsuccessful attempts):

```
.content {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
}

li {
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
       -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
            column-break-inside:avoid;
           break-inside: avoid-column;
             page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed some `div`s that were splitting onto the next column by adding

```
overflow: auto
```

to the child `div`s.

*Realized it only fixes it in Firefox!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem i think and found a solution in this:

```
-webkit-column-fill: auto; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-fill: auto; /* Firefox */
column-fill: auto;
```

Working also in FF 38.0.5: http://jsfiddle.net/rkzj8qnv/

Answer (score 3):

```
<style>
ul li{display: table;}  
</style>
```

works perfectly

Comment: This removes bullets in a list

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround for Firefox is to set the CSS property "display" of the element you don't want to have a break inside to "table". I don't know if it works for the LI tag (you'll probably lose the list -item-style), but it works for the P tag.

Comment: This solution removes the list item, so if you're using order lists for example this wouldn't be an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I made an update of the actual answer.

This seems to be working on firefox and chrome: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gatsbimantico/QJeB7/1/embedded/result/

```
.x{
columns: 5em;
-webkit-columns: 5em; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-columns: 5em; /* Firefox */
}
.x li{
    float:left;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

**Note:** The *float* property seems to be the one making the block behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
page-break-inside: avoid;
break-inside: avoid;
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid-column;
page-break-inside: avoid-column;
break-inside: avoid-column;
```

...worked for me, might work for you.

Comment: Seems each of the 3 unique properties are defined twice here.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might only apply to certain circumstances; If you set a height to your elements, this will be obeyed by the column styling. There-by keeping anything that is contained within that height to a row.

I had a list, like the op, but it contained two elements, items and buttons to act upon those items. I treated it like a table `<ul> - table`, `<li> - table-row`, `<div> - table-cell` put the UL in a 4 column layout. The columns were sometimes being split between the item and it's buttons. The trick I used was to give the Div elements a line height to cover the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the propertis is showing invalid when I am going to apply such as

```
  page-break-inside: avoid-column;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid-column;
```

and when I am checking is responsiveness it not working fine for me...

Anyone can provide me a solution for the same...