# Can a multi column list have individually elastic columns?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This list of [speakers from jQuery Portland](http://events.jquery.org/2013/portland/#speakers) uses a 3 column layout (at desktop browser widths) in which individual elements can grow to displace items beneath them, without affecting other columns. The downside is that this requires 3 column containers in the markup.

Is it possible to get the same effect with a simple list, and no column containers with only css?

I've never used flexbox before, but I can't seem to make items wrap without coupling rows between columns [codepen example](http://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/Esyuf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to get the same effect with a simple list, and no column containers with only css?

Answer to this: You can also use `column-count`

[demo](http://cdpn.io/isgCI)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much [another demo](http://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/Esyuf)

Comment: You added your demo as an edit while I was testing with `column-count` on my own ;) Also the `break-inside` property came in handy, as detailed in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785374/how-to-prevent-column-break-within-an-element).

Comment: Be aware that Firefox does not support break-inside, and webkit browsers use the old name of column-break-inside (prefixed).