# Remove gap between Div box using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm getting all data from mysql database and showing in CSS Div box **{class = box}** using php while loop. Now all data is showing perfectly but I see that there a big gap between the boxes. How can i remove the gap/space ? It's look like the following image:

[image]

**I'm using following CSS Code:**

```
.box{
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width:320px;    
    border:1px #ccc solid;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

**It's should be show like http://www.pinterest.com/ home page.**

**Here is the php code:**

```
<?php
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM keyword_type ORDER BY keyword_full_name ASC");
$numType =  mysql_num_rows($query);

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 

    $typeID =  $result['keyword_typeID'];
    $keywordType =  strtoupper($result['keyword_full_name']);

    echo "<div class='box'>";

    echo "<h3><strong>$keywordType</strong></h3>";
    $query2 =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE keyword_typeID = '$typeID' ORDER BY keywordName ASC ");
    $num2 =  mysql_num_rows($query2);

    while($result2 =  mysql_fetch_array($query2)){

        $kid = $result2['kid'];
        $keywordName = ucfirst($result2['keywordName']);

        $query4 =  mysql_query("SELECT kid FROM userkeywords WHERE cdid = '$cdid' AND kid='$kid'");
        $num = mysql_num_rows($query4);

        if($num > 0){
            $class = "keywordHighlight";    
        }else{
            $class = "";
        }

        echo "<div onclick='keywordclick($kid,$cdid);' class='$class'>$keywordName</div>";          


    }
    echo "</div>";

}

?>
```

Any help ?

Comment: negative margin for particular box will help you...

Comment: @C-linkNepal How can I do this ?

Comment: PHP is irrelevant here. It's about styling the output; the fact it came from PHP/MySQL is of no consequence to your question.

Comment: @Shibbir: I would sincerely recommend to remove the PHP/MySQL stuff and instead post the resulting HTML.

Comment: I think @lxg was talking about the code. Since this is a markup issue, only the outputted HTML is relevant. It will be impossible for us to run this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved a similar issue by dividing the page into columns. The divs are then basically underneath each other. This is a simple, CSS only solution, but it's not perfect. There is a gap at the bottom of the page, and above that, the order changes of course from a horizontal to a vertical ordering.

Nevertheless, it might be useful for you. This is the page it is used on:

http://www.eftepedia.nl/lemma/Categorie%C3%ABn

You can do this with CSS columns, like this:

```
.container {
    -webkit-columns: auto 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns: auto 3; /* Firefox */
    columns: auto 3;
}
```

For the boxes you can use `break-inside: avoid-column;` to avoid them breaking over multiple columns. 
Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785374/how-to-prevent-column-break-within-an-element) for more information about specific issues with that.

Bringing it together in a minimal example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/02f4wqcm/

Comment: Wow! Exactly that I want!

Comment: But how they do this ?

Comment: I added explanation and a fiddle, that also clearly shows the vertical ordering. I hope that's not an issue for you.

Comment: See also a polyfill for older browsers https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery for removing the spaces.

Try following libraries

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html

http://packery.metafizzy.co/options.html