# CSS positioning div into two column properly

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem in positioning a div if one post is contain many text. The div will apparently getting a bigger space. Here is the [link of my code](http://jsbin.com/judaduremibi/1/edit)
[image: visualize what ouput I want to display.]

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div>DIV 1 Sample text</div>
   <div> DIV 2 Sample text Sample text Sample text</div>
   <div> DIV 3 Sample text Sample text Sample text</div>
   <div> DIV 4</div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:400px;
}

.container div {
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    background:red;
    margin:2px;
}
```

Comment: We don't like to see jsbin code. Please include the code inside the question...

Comment: This types of questions are asked daily... Please see the  duplicate question [Remove gap between Div box using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709393/remove-gap-between-div-box-using-css)

Comment: @C-linkNepal I've check sir the link you've given. However the css column: auto 3 is the code because it has 3 column gaps. in my case what if DIV 2 container many many text sir. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the the two left divs in one div and two right divs in another div

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
   <div>DIV 1 Sample text</div>
   <div> DIV 2 Sample text Sample text Sample 
     text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    <div> DIV 3 Sample text Sample text Sample 
    text</div><div> DIV 4</div> </div>   
    </div>
```

Comment: May want to include the css for classes `right` and `left` is right regardless but may seal the deal

Comment: the code I've provided is an ajax json data. it is process in the server. so probably you cannot put left right class in the div. Anyway, thanks for the effort brah.

Comment: if you cannot change the order You can try to wrap the divs or arrange using jquery after getting the response from the server .

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
   <div>DIV 1 Sample text</div>
   <div> DIV 3 Sample text Sample text Sample text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
    <div> DIV 2 Sample text Sample text Sample text</div>
    <div> DIV 4</div> </div>   
    </div>
```

and css should be

```
.container {

  width:400px;

}

.container .left {
  float:left;
  width:180px;
  background:red;
  margin:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is masonry kind of approach.

Using salvattore (NOT TESTED)

```
<div id="grid" data-columns>
    <div>Item #1</div>
    <div>Item #2</div>
    <div>Item #3</div>
    <div>Item #4</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#grid[data-columns]::before {
    content: '2 .column.size-1of2';
}

.column { float: left; }
.size-1of2 { width: 50%; }
```

Refer http://salvattore.com/ to achieve masonry