# css & javascript alignment issue. Is this even possible in css?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a rather difficult issue I'm stuck on I would appreciate some insight to if this is even possible with CSS.  I have 6 divs, 1-3 need to be in a left column, and 4-6 in a right column. When you click any of the divs, they hide using jquery hide(). The part I am finding difficult is when you remove one div, I need them to reorder in a specific way. Please see attached image for the order / reorder proses im going for. see my fiddle for my progress, thanks a bunch for the help.

https://jsfiddle.net/m44pzvz4/

```
 <div id="container">
     <div class="child">1</div>
     <div class="child">2</div>
     <div class="child">3</div>
     <div class="child">4</div>
     <div class="child">5</div>
     <div class="child">6</div>  
 </div>
```

[image]

So you can see that if any 1-3 div is removed, the divs in 4-6 need to b moved from left column to the last spot in the first column.

Comment: Are you always going to have exactly 6 elements?

Comment: yes. there will always be a max of 6.

Comment: Use child selectors to float the first three items to the left. When an item is hidden, it won't be considered one of the first three children, and it will shift everything like you described.

Comment: I did attempt that, but I found that when you remove a div with .toggle() it still holds its nth-of-type position. So even when its removed form page .nth-of-type(1) still is .nth-of-type(1). As apposed to .nth-of-type(2) becoming .nth-of-type(1).

Comment: Think of it as a grid, leave your cells alone and just worry about moving the data. Eg: if  4 is removed shift 5s data to where 4's element is.

Comment: ahh yes I see thats a good approach to it.

Comment: Heres an alternate solution using javascript, you could give it a shot.https://jsfiddle.net/m44pzvz4/2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `flex-flow: column wrap`:

```js
$(".item").each(function() {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    $(this).hide()
  });
});

$("button").each(function(index) {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    $('#' + (index + 1)).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {    
  display: -webkit-flex;     
  display: flex;             
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.r { background-color: #bf616a; }
.o { background-color: #d08770; }
.y { background-color: #ebcb8b; }
.g { background-color: #a3be8c; }
.b { background-color: #96b5b4; }
.v { background-color: #8fa1b3; }

.layout {  
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;        
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <div id='1' class="item r">1</div>
    <div id='2' class="item o">2</div>
    <div id='3' class="item y">3</div>
    <div id='4' class="item g">4</div>
    <div id='5' class="item b">5</div>
    <div id='6' class="item v">6</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    Toggles:
    <div>1
      <button>toggle</button>
    </div>
    <div>2
      <button>toggle</button>
    </div>
    <div>3
      <button>toggle</button>
    </div>
    <div>4
      <button>toggle</button>
    </div>
    <div>5
      <button>toggle</button>
    </div>
    <div>6
      <button>toggle</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a browser prefix to make this safari compatible?

Comment: No worries I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Thansk so much, tonight im definitely reading more on  display: -webkit-flex;     
  display: flex;             
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;

Answer (score 10):

Use CSS columns and remove the `float` properties of your children:

```css
#container {
  /* ... */
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Additionally, to prevent your boxes from splitting between columns (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785374/how-to-prevent-column-break-within-an-element)):

```
.child {
    /* ... */
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari */
    page-break-inside: avoid;           /* Theoretically FF 20+ */
    break-inside: avoid-column;         /* IE 11 */
    display:table;                      /* Actually FF 20+ */
}
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: hahah yes!! I knew it would come to the columns. That was quick by the way your the man.

Comment: This is the right answer, but it's worth noting that it only works in IE10 and above.

Comment: It does have some bugs thou.

Comment: Yeah that 4th div seems to get stuck half way.

Comment: Oh, didn't get that bug in Chrome. Does this solve it? https://jsfiddle.net/2ohvqo8r/ I added some properties found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785374/how-to-prevent-column-break-within-an-element

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @btevfik , I don't have Safari.

Comment: yes that looks better, I guess the one thing I wasn't totally clear about is that first column always needs to have 3 divs in it. My bad.

Comment: @nick Does it work after adding a `border-box` reset like this? https://jsfiddle.net/2mrwe1x1/

Comment: @nick What if someone clicks on 4 of them?

Comment: Then the remaining 2 would fill the 1 and 2 spot on the left column.This flex solution below seems to be correct let me look more into it.

Comment: Thanks for your help blex I really appreciate it.

Comment: @nick No problem, glad you found a solution with DTing