# Columns property not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a three column layout for my website. When I use the column property and set it to "3" columns, it doesn't align correctly. Each column after the previous seems to be pushed down a little bit more. Is there a way to correct this? It does the same thing when I set the column count to "5" column and minimize the window

```css
.widget-column {
  columns: 5em 3;
  /* Test with 5 columns */
  -moz-columns: 5em 3;
  /* Test with 5 columns */
  -webkit-columns: 5em 3;
  /* Test with 5 columns */
}
.widget-column p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-column">
  <p>Column</p>
  <p>Column</p>
  <p>Column</p>
  <p>Column</p>
  <p>Column</p>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gymmtmm0/1/)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent column break within an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785374/how-to-prevent-column-break-within-an-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `<p>` is a block level element, it adds a newline both before and after the element. But, you can make it as inline-block level, by setting `display:inline-block;` plus `width:100%;` for expanding the width.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.widget-column {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  columns: 5em 3;
  -o-columns: 5em 3;
  -ms-columns: 5em 3;
  -moz-columns: 5em 3;
  -webkit-columns: 5em 3;
  column-gap: 0px;
  -o-column-gap: 0px;
  -ms-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
}
.widget-column p {
  background: #EEE;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-column">
  <p>Column</p>
  <p>Column</p>
  <p>Column</p>
  <p>Column</p>
  <p>Column</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You have to use <span> in case of <p> tag, <p> tag by default starts from next line
```

Here is the plnk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/n4TlD6nVSqOa9U5F2PON?p=preview