# How to Display list item irrespective of others list item?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to over right the ul li default property to achieve certain structure. Someone suggest the right way of doing this.

I am having 7 list item with margin-bottom of 5px. Used float left to display them in the 2 column. First Li has one line content and the second li (right side) has two line content. So my third li which is in the left side automatically start 5 px margin from the 2nd li. But I want it(3rd list item (li)) to take 5px margin from first li which in the left side. 
I want all my list item to take only margin-bottom of 5px.

```
 <div class="lst-container">
      <ul class="bullet-list">
             <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
              <li><a href="">ContentContent Content </a></li>
              <li><a href=""> Content content content</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Content content</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Content content</a></li>

         </ul>
      </div>



   [Jsfiddle][1] https://jsfiddle.net/4Lvnut4p/1/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `column-count` property. I updated your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lvnut4p/3/

Comment: When I increase the content of list3 it display in the 2nd column  
Updated in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4Lvnut4p/5/

Comment: Prevent column break: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785374/how-to-prevent-column-break-within-an-element/7785711#7785711