# CSS3 - masonry layout like pinterest - columns / boxes are being split

Tags: css, masonry

I have about 6 divs containing text and images.  They all vary in length but are the same width.  I therefore want to display like Pinterest which I have achieved.

However, the divs are split over multiple columns. How do I stop this from happening?  The CSS I have used is below the image.

```
.masonry {
     margin: 1.5em 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
}

.masonry .feedback-box{
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}​

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by broken?

Comment: That's how CSS columns work...if you want a proper masonry layout...you'd have to use a masonry type JS solution.

Comment: In the image you can see how they are broken.  The divs are split over multiple columns.

Comment: is there no way to achieve this without JQuery?  and if I use Jquery what is the simplest solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use  **break-inside: avoid;** see below:

```
.masonry {
     margin: 1.5em 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
}

#client-feedbacks .feedback-box {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        float:none !important;
        -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; 
        page-break-inside: avoid; 
        break-inside: avoid; 
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **`overflow: hidden;`** to the items you don't want to be split across columns in Firefox and **`display: inline-block`** in Chrome like you did.
Something like:

```
.masonry .feedback-box{
    display: inline-block; /* Chrome */
    /*width: 100% !important; ?? */
    overflow: hidden; /* Firefox */
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
.masonry .feedback-box:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Test pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojeVmm?editors=010

Only tested on Firefox and Chrome, not IE11 or Safari.

Probable duplicate of **[How to prevent column break within an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785374/how-to-prevent-column-break-within-an-element)**

Comment: Sorry that didn't work in all browsers.  I found  break-inside: avoid; was what I needed.