# How to prevent breaking a div in two with CSS column property with cross browser support?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<section style="-webkit-column-count:3">
  <div class="item">
    <h2></h2>
    <p>…</p>
    <p> Read More &mdash; <a  href="link.htm"></a></p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  ..
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
</section>
```

At the bottom of the page, the div with item class splits in two to maintain equal height of columns. How can I keep individual div together at the bottom?
Let me know If I am not explaining the question clearly.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j35toyju/

You will see that the items are not in a complete block. Sometimes, the heading is at bottom and rest of the div at top. Other times everything is at bottom and just link is at top.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785374/how-to-prevent-column-break-within-an-element) provide an answer but it only works in Google Chrome. Is there any way to make it work in all browsers. With use of JavaScript if not possible in pure CSS?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by "keep individual div together at the bottom". Can you clarify that?

Comment: Can you include some of your css to show this in action, or your script? At the moment it is hard to draw any conclusions from this html snippet.

Comment: @TravisJ I have added a fiddle. I  hope it clear things up. Let me know if I need to make any more changes. Thanks :)

Comment: @showdev, Is there no way to solve this issue in cross browser manner?

Comment: @showdev could you please remove the duplicate tag? The solution in other answer works only for chrome. It has been about four years, so there might be a better solution. :)

Comment: The updated part of the accepted answer [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/j35toyju/3/) in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. There seem to be other cross-browser-related answers there, as well. Which solution are you trying and in which browser/version are you having trouble?

Comment: I am sorry, I was using `page-break-inside: avoid;` for Firefox instead of `display:table;`. :) I noticed it later in your fiddle.