# How to force div to fill empty space on left side of another, higher div

Tags: html, css, positioning, floating

Please look at the example below. I'm trying to put my `yellow` div under `red` div and on the left side of bottom half of `green`. If i use `clear: left` it will jump down, but it lefts empty space above. I want it to fill this space.

Here's example:
[https://jsfiddle.net/enqqr2w8/](https://jsfiddle.net/enqqr2w8/1/)

Comment: Would you be able to use a `table` arrangement?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#redyellow
{
 width: 100px;
 height: 200px;
 float: left;
}
#red
{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 float: left;
}
#green
{
 width: 100px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
}
#blue
{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;
}
#yellow
{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: yellow;
 float: left;
}
body
{
 width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="redyellow">
  <div id="red">
 aa
 </div>
  <div id="yellow">
 aa
 </div>
  </div>
 <div id="green">
 aa
 </div>
 <div id="blue">
 aa
 </div>
</body>
```

Does this work for you?

EDIT: I have found a way to make dynamic columns with only CSS3:

```css
div
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
#red {
 background-color: red;
}
#green
{
 height: 200px;
 background-color: green;
}
#blue
{
 background-color: blue;
}
#yellow
{
 background-color: yellow;
}
#orange
{
 background-color: orange;
}
#black
{
 background-color: black;
}
body
{
  width: 300px;
  columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="yellow"></div>
 <div id="green"></div>
 <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="orange"></div>
</body>
```

Sources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785374/how-to-prevent-column-break-within-an-element), [2](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp), [3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-count), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Unfortunatelly i can't do it like that. Im actually printing this divs with php loop (cant use ajax or jquery plugins such as Masonry) so im not able to do 'columns' like yours. Its like yellow div is 4 in order and 5th have to be under blue one.

Comment: @Arthi What are you talking about? This uses no jQuery or AJAX, only one extra element and CSS definition.

Comment: @Arthi Okay, I see what you are saying, I will try to think of something else.

Comment: @Arthi How does it look now? I added an extra orange block to show what it would look like.