# Divs of varying size don't float correctly

Tags: css

If I float:left a bunch of divs that are the same dimensions, it seems to work well, for example:
[divs properly floating](https://jsfiddle.net/cdh53rvp/1/)

However, if one of the divs is taller than the others, only the first div will float left of it and the rest are all pushed to the right. I can reproduce this by increasing the height of divtwo in the example:

```
div.divone{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

div.divtwo{
  width:100px;
  height:250px;
  background-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

<div class="divone">abc</div>
<div class="divtwo">abc</div>
<div class="divone">abc</div>
<div class="divone">abc</div>
<div class="divone">abc</div>
<div class="divone">abc</div>
```

[An image of the two examples side by side with an arrow pointing to where I'm expecting the divs to go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNWcD.jpg)

What should I do to get those small divs to properly fit in the empty space to the left of the tall div?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for masonary type layouts.  Here's a good blog post.

https://medium.com/@_jh3y/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a#.64f1qm9a

Answer (score 0):

[Taken from my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39319085/5732397)

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
#red {
 background-color: red;
}
#green {
 height: 250px;
 background-color: green;
}
#blue {
 background-color: blue;
}
#yellow {
 background-color: yellow;
}
#orange {
 background-color: orange;
}
body {
  width: 300px;
  columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="yellow"></div>
 <div id="green"></div>
 <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="orange"></div>
</body>
```

You can use CSS columns to achieve this effect quite easily.