# Responsive multi-column list with column order

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create an ordered multi-column list, but am struggling with CSS Grid layout rules.

The desired outcome should be responsive. On small screens 2 grid columns, on larger screens up to 4, all while maintaining a column order.

Instead of being ordered like this:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15
```

They should be ordered like this:

```
1 5 9  13
2 6 10 14
3 7 11 15
4 8 12
```

I feel I am close with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pojygfkc/1/).

```css
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: grey;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(33.333%, 50%));
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1em);
}

li {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
</ol>
```

Especially, I am struggling with these points:

a) `grid-auto-flow: column` is required to make the column wrapping work, but also forces me to add `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1em)` to specify a row count, which breaks the responsiveness. Is there a way to calculate the row count automatically based on content and column count?

b) Why are the columns widths not evenly distributed and why don't they adapt to the screen size? Isn't this what `minmax` is for?

Comment: For some reason using `grid-auto-flow: column` seems to break the auto-fill mechanism for the rows. The only way I managed to pull this off is with media queries. https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/JJLpgR/?editors=1100 - but I suppose that's cheating :)

Answer (score 1):

Tweak with column count to change number of columns :)

```css
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  /*---*/
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  background-color: grey;
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through your two sticking points.

1. > `grid-auto-flow: column` is required to make the column wrapping work, but also forces me to add `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1em)` to specify a row count, which breaks the responsiveness. Is there a way to calculate the row count automatically based on content and column count?

`grid-auto-flow: column` *does not* make column wrapping work. In fact, it does the exact opposite. The rule creates new columns to accommodate additional grid items.

Here's how it works (from the spec):

> [**7.7. Automatic Placement: the `grid-auto-flow`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property)
>
> Grid items that aren’t explicitly placed are automatically placed into
>   an unoccupied space in the grid container by the auto-placement
>   algorithm.
>
> `grid-auto-flow` controls how the auto-placement algorithm works,
>   specifying exactly how auto-placed items get flowed into the grid.
>
> ***`column`***
>
> The auto-placement algorithm places items by filling each column in
>   turn, adding new columns as necessary.
>
> ***`row`***
>
> The auto-placement algorithm places items by filling each row in turn, adding new rows as necessary. If neither `row` nor `column` is provided, `row` is assumed.

With regard to your question:

> Is there a way to calculate the row count automatically based on content and column count?

With CSS Grid alone, I don't believe so. As it says in the spec, `grid-auto-flow` is designed to add new tracks in the specified direction (`column` / `row`).

If it can be done with Grid, then it wouldn't be fully automatic. You would need at least some defined placement and, I would guess, media queries.

Lastly, with regard to column wrapping, that comes from the `auto-fit` or `auto-fill` values in the `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` properties.

---

2. > Why are the column widths not evenly distributed and why don't they adapt to the screen size? Isn't this what `minmax` is for?

This goes back to the spec section highlighted above.

This is your column-sizing code:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(33.333%, 50%));
```

This translates to: *The width of each explicit column must be a minimum of 33.333% and a maximum of 50%.*

The problem is that the third column is not *explicit*. It is *implicit*, as it is being added to the grid by the auto-placement algorithm, under the guidance of `grid-auto-flow: column`. So this column is not subject to `grid-template-columns`, which deals solely with [*explicit track sizing*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing).

The properties for [*implicit track sizing*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks) are `grid-auto-columns` and `grid-auto-rows`. Their default value is `auto`, which is what you're seeing in your layout: The third column is the width of its content.

```css
ol {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(33.333%, 50%));
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1em);

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: grey;
}

li {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
</ol>
```

Once you set the value of `grid-auto-columns`, the third column can be properly sized.

```css
ol {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(33.333%, 50%));
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1em);
  grid-auto-columns: 33.333%; /* NEW */

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: grey;
}

li {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
</ol>
```

---

Of course, the information above is intended to be an explanation, not a solution to the main problem, as I don't believe CSS Grid provides one.

Comment: In particular, note `auto-fill` will use the *max* size to calculate how many tracks to create, if possible. In this case, 50% is compatible with that, so it'll make two columns.  (There's never a reason to use auto-fill with percentages, since you trivially know how many columns will fit just from simple division.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I've noticed that `minmax()` uses *max* in track-sizing calculations. The issue is explored here: [`minmax()` defaulting to max](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50654400/3597276). Thanks for [posting an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52377092/3597276).  @Xanthir

Comment: Also, with regard to the question in this post, it's explored in more detail here: [Make grid container fill columns not rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44092529/3597276). If there is, in fact, a way for Grid to automatically add columns after filling all vertical space (like CSS Columns), you may want to mention it there. @Xanthir