# Css grid styling 2 vertical columns infinite rows from 2 different types of div

Tags: html, css

I have this html-code generated from a xml-file which is generated from latex code and I can't change the html output. I work on an indological edition of an anient yoga text. I not just want to have a nice latex document for printing my edition. I want to also have a web edition simultanously. So my lualatex code is processed putting out an xml-file which a xslt2 processor processes to an html file. This is the html:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: LinuxLibertineDisplay0Regular, times, serif;
    src: url(fonts/LinLibertine_DR.woff);
}
/* {box-sizing: border-box;}*/
/*body {background-color: #FFFFFF; font-family: 'LinuxLibertineDisplayORegular'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18px; padding: 20px 100px 20px; width: 1600px;}*/
    body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
    grid-gap: 0.5rem;
 }

h1 {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: none;
}

.edition,
.translation {
    display: inherit;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    row-gap: 10px
}

.edition {
    grid-column-start: 1;
}

.translation {
    grid-column-start: 2;
}

.edition > div[type="ed"] {
    background-color: #def;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.translation > div[type="trans"] {
  background-color: #abc;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}   

ul {list-style: circle;}

ul.dash {list-style: none; margin-left: .5em; padding-left: .5em;}
ul.dash > li:before {display: inline-block; content: "–"; width: 1em; margin-left: 0em;}

a:link {color: black; text-decoration: underline;}
a:visited {color: black; text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover {color: black; text-decoration: none;}
a:active {color: black; text-decoration: underline;}

p {padding-left: .5em; padding-right: .5em;}

h4 {margin-bottom: 0px;}
mark {background-color: #FFFFCC;}
q:before {content: "»";}
q:after {content: "«";}

.noindent {padding: 0px;}
.comm {padding-left: 1em; padding-right: 1em;}
.app {width: 80%; text-align: left; font-size: 10px; padding-left: 1em;}
.lem {display:inline-block;}
.ref {font-size: 14px; padding: inherit;}
.lb {font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;}
.lb:before {content: "["}
.lb:after {content: "]"}
.pb {font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;}
.pb:before {content: " ["}
.pb:after {content: "] "}
.note {font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;}
.note:before {content: " ["}
.note:after {content: "] "}
.subhead {font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;}
.appnote {font-size: 14px;}
.appnote:before {content: " ["}
.appnote:after {content: "] "}
.hi {font-style: italic}
.sic:before {content: "†"}
.sic:after {content: "†"}
.corr {color: #008000;}
.supplied {color: #1E90FF;}
.surplus {color: #ff3333;}
.unclear {color: #D2B48C;}

/* custom renditions */
.b, .bf, .textbf, .bold {font-weight: bold}
.i, .it, .textit, .italic {font-style: italic}
.u, .underline {text-decoration: underline}
.blue {color: #0000e6;}
.red {color: #b30000;}

.row:after {content: ""; display: table; clear: both;}
.column {float: left; width: 50%; padding-left: .5em; padding-right: .5em;}
.analysis {font-size: 14px; color: #0066ff; padding-left: .5em; padding-right: .5em; padding-top: .1em;}
.analysis:before {content: "["}
.analysis:after {content: "]"}

div.wapp:hover  span.lem {background-color: #FFFFCC;}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    body {font-size: 16px;}
    .column {width: 100%;}
    .analysis {width: 100%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    body {padding: 10px;}
    .app {width: 90%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
    body {width: auto; padding: 20px;}
}

#toc_container {background: #f9f9f9 none repeat scroll 0 0; border: 1px solid #aaa; display: table; font-size: 95%; margin-bottom: 1em; padding: 1em; width: auto;}
.toc_title {font-weight: 700; text-align: center;}    
#toc_container li, #toc_container ul, #toc_container ul li{list-style: outside none none !important; padding-left: .5em;}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1></h1>
      
      <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-edition_1" class="edition">
         <div type="ed">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Maṅgala statement</h3>
            <centerline>
               <textrm><small>[Introduction]</small></textrm>
            </centerline> 
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
               <p> <mark>śrī gaṇeśāya namaḥ</mark> // <mark>atha rājayogaprakāro likhyate</mark> // </p>
               <div class="app"><span class="lem">śrī gaṇeśāya namaḥ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> śrī ṇe ya maḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>), śrī gurave namaḥ (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a>), śrī sarasvatyai namaḥ śrī nirañjanāya namaḥ (<a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>), oṃ śrī niraṃjanāya (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
               <div class="app"><span class="lem">atha rājayogaprakāro likhyate (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>) ]</span> atha rājayogaprakāra likhyate (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>), rājayogāntargataḥ / binduyogaḥ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>), atha tattvabiṃduyogaprāraṃbhaḥ (<a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a>), atha rājayoga liṣyate (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>), atha rājayoga likhyate (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div type="ed">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Intro</h3>
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
               <p> rājayogasyedaṃ phalaṃ / yena rājayogenānekarājyabhogasamaya eva / anekapārthivavinoda<mark>prekṣaṇasamaya</mark> eva / bahutarakālaṃ śarīrasthitirbhavati / sa <mark>eva</mark> rājayogaḥ / tasyaite bhedāḥ / </p>
               <div class="app"><span class="lem">prekṣaṇasamaya (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> prekṣyaṇasamaya (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
               <div class="app"><span class="lem">eva (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> evaṃ (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div type="ed">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">The 15 Yogas</h3>
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="row">
               <div class="column">
                  <div class="wapp">
                     <p>kriyāyogaḥ / jñānayogaḥ / <mark>cāryayogaḥ</mark> / haṭhayogaḥ / karmayogaḥ / <mark>layayogaḥ</mark> / dhyānayogaḥ / mantrayogaḥ / <mark>lakṣyayogaḥ</mark> / vāsanāyogaḥ / śivayogaḥ / brahmayogaḥ / advaitayogaḥ / <mark>siddhayogaḥ / rājayogaḥ</mark> / <mark>ete pañcadaśayogāḥ</mark> //</p>
                     <div class="app"><span class="lem">cāryayogaḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> tvaryāyogaḥ (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
                     <div class="app"><span class="lem">layayogaḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> nayayogaḥ (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
                     <div class="app"><span class="lem">lakṣyayogaḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> lakṣayogaḥ (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
                     <div class="app"><span class="lem">siddhayogaḥ / rājayogaḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> rājayogaḥ / siddhayogaḥ (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
                     <div class="app"><span class="lem">ete pañcadaśayogāḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> evaṃ paṃcadaśāyogā bhavaṃti (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="column">
                  <p class="analysis">The initial codification of 15 yogas appears in N1,P,D1,U1 and U2. It is ommitted
                     in E and L. B can't be determined due to missing folios. P is the only witness which
                     numbers the yogas with devanāgarī-digits. The other witnesses separate the list with
                     single or double daṇḍas.</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div type="ed">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Kriyāyoga</h3>
            <centerline>
               <textrm><small>[Description of <span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="italic">kriyāyoga</span>]</small></textrm>
            </centerline> 
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
               <p><mark>idānīṃ</mark> <mark>kriyāyogasya</mark> lakṣaṇaṃ <mark>kathyate</mark>/</p>
               <div class="app"><span class="lem">idānīṃ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> atha (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
               <div class="app"><span class="lem">kriyāyogasya (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> kriyāyogas (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
               <div class="app"><span class="lem">kathyate (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> kathayate (<a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>), \om  (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-translation_1" class="translation">
         <div type="trans">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Maṅgala statement</h3>
            <centerline>
               <textrm><small>[Introduction]</small></textrm>
            </centerline> 
            <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Homage to Śrī Gaṇeśa. Now the methods of rājayoga are laid down. </p>
         </div>
         <div type="trans">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Intro</h3>
            <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">This is the result of <span class="italic">rājayoga</span><span class="note">This statement seems unconnected to the definition of rājayoga that follows.</span>: <span class="italic">Rājayoga</span> is that by which longterm durability of the body arises even amongst manifold royal
               pleasures even amongst the manifold royal entertainments and spectacle. This truly
               is <span class="italic">rājayoga</span>. Of this [<span class="italic">rājayoga</span>] these are the varieties: </p>
         </div>
         <div type="trans">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">The 15 Yogas</h3>
            <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">1. Yoga of [mental] action (<span class="italic">kriyāyoga</span>), 2. Yoga of knowledge (<span class="italic">jñānayoga</span>), 3. Yoga of wandering (<span class="italic">caryāyoga</span>), 4. Yoga of force (<span class="italic">haṭhayoga</span>), 5. Yoga of deeds (<span class="italic">karmayoga</span>), 6. Yoga of absorption (<span class="italic">layayoga</span>), 7. Yoga of meditation (<span class="italic">dhyānayoga</span>), 8. Yoga of mantras (<span class="italic">mantrayoga</span>), 9. Yoga of fixation objects (<span class="italic">lakṣyayoga</span>), 10. Yoga of mental residues (<span class="italic">vāsanāyoga</span>), 11. Yoga of Śiva (<span class="italic">śivayoga</span>), 12. Yoga of Brahman (<span class="italic">brahmayoga</span>), 13. Yoga of non-duality (<span class="italic">advaitayoga</span>), 14. Yoga of completion (<span class="italic">siddhayoga</span>) 15. Yoga of kings (<span class="italic">rājayoga</span>). These are the fifteen <span class="italic">yoga</span>s.<span class="note">At the current stage of research it is not clear if this list is a later addition
                  by another scribe or, if indeed it originally stems from Rāmacandra. The list suggests
                  a text following the order of yogas according to this list. However, the order and
                  even the designation of some of the yogas given in the list is just followed very
                  loosely in the text.</span></p>
         </div>
         <div type="trans">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Kriyāyoga</h3>
            <centerline>
               <textrm><small>[Description of <span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="italic">kriyāyoga</span>]</small></textrm>
            </centerline> 
            <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Now the characteristic of the Yoga of [mental] action (<span class="italic">kriyāyoga</span>) described.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

I would like to display the html using css in two columns with infinite rows as my edition and the translation goes. The first row is supposed to display the translation and the following row is supposed to display the respective translation.

This should continuously be in alignment.

I can't change the html too mucg. I have to do it by applying css. So I think it is a good idea to access by choosing the div markup which has n=1 and n=2.

Edition part 1 is marked by type="ed" and should go into first column first row. Translation of part 1 it is marked by type="trans" and should go into second column first row.
Edition part 2 is marked by type="ed" and should go into first column second row.
Translation of part 2 is marked by type="trans" and should go into second column second row.

And potentially so on and so forth.

But somehow I can't figure it out. I am sitting here since 9 hours and it does not work.

Can you please help me?

Thank you and best wishes,
enjotel

...................

Comment: Hello. Please tell me, should the `<h1></h1>` tag be above the blocks, or below (after) the blocks?

Comment: Hello @s.kuznetsov <h1></h1> should be above the blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need such a result?

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
    grid-gap: 0.5rem;
}

h1 {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: none;
}

.edition,
.translation {
    display: inherit;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.edition {
    grid-column-start: 2;
}

.translation {
    grid-column-start: 1;
}

.edition > div[type="ed"] {
    background-color: #def;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.translation > div[type="trans"] {
    background-color: #abc;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>This is title</h1>
    <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-edition_1" class="edition">
        <div type="ed">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">intro1</h3>
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
                <p><mark>śrī gaṇeśāya namaḥ</mark> // <mark>atha rājayogaprakāro likhyate</mark> //</p>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">
                        śrī gaṇeśāya namaḥ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>
                        <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]
                    </span>
                    śrī ṇe ya maḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>), śrī gurave namaḥ (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a>), śrī sarasvatyai namaḥ śrī nirañjanāya namaḥ (<a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>), oṃ
                    śrī niraṃjanāya (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)
                </div>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">atha rājayogaprakāro likhyate (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>) ]</span> atha rājayogaprakāra likhyate (
                    <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>), rājayogāntargataḥ / binduyogaḥ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>), atha tattvabiṃduyogaprāraṃbhaḥ (<a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a>), atha rājayoga
                    liṣyate (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>), atha rājayoga likhyate (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div type="ed">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">rajayoga</h3>
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
                <p>rājayogasyedaṃ phalaṃ / yena rājayogenānekarājyabhogasamaya eva / anekapārthivavinoda<mark>prekṣaṇasamaya</mark> eva / bahutarakālaṃ śarīrasthitirbhavati / sa <mark>eva</mark> rājayogaḥ / tasyaite bhedāḥ /</p>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">prekṣaṇasamaya (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span>
                    prekṣyaṇasamaya (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)
                </div>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">eva (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> evaṃ (
                    <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-translation_1" class="translation">
        <div type="trans">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">intro1</h3>
            Homage to Śrī Gaṇeśa. Now the methods of rājayoga are laid down.
        </div>
        <div type="trans">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">rajayoga</h3>
            Rājayoga is that by which longterm durability of the body arises even amongst manifold royal pleasures even amongst the manifold royal entertainments and spectacle. This truly is rājayoga. Of this [rājayoga] these are the
            varieties:
        </div>
    </div>
     <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-edition_1" class="edition">
        <div type="ed">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">intro1</h3>
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
                <p><mark>śrī gaṇeśāya namaḥ</mark> // <mark>atha rājayogaprakāro likhyate</mark> //</p>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">
                        śrī gaṇeśāya namaḥ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>
                        <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]
                    </span>
                    śrī ṇe ya maḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>), śrī gurave namaḥ (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a>), śrī sarasvatyai namaḥ śrī nirañjanāya namaḥ (<a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>), oṃ
                    śrī niraṃjanāya (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)
                </div>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">atha rājayogaprakāro likhyate (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>) ]</span> atha rājayogaprakāra likhyate (
                    <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>), rājayogāntargataḥ / binduyogaḥ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>), atha tattvabiṃduyogaprāraṃbhaḥ (<a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a>), atha rājayoga
                    liṣyate (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>), atha rājayoga likhyate (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div type="ed">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">rajayoga</h3>
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
                <p>rājayogasyedaṃ phalaṃ / yena rājayogenānekarājyabhogasamaya eva / anekapārthivavinoda<mark>prekṣaṇasamaya</mark> eva / bahutarakālaṃ śarīrasthitirbhavati / sa <mark>eva</mark> rājayogaḥ / tasyaite bhedāḥ /</p>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">prekṣaṇasamaya (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span>
                    prekṣyaṇasamaya (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)
                </div>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">eva (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> evaṃ (
                    <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-translation_1" class="translation">
        <div type="trans">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">intro1</h3>
            Homage to Śrī Gaṇeśa. Now the methods of rājayoga are laid down.
        </div>
        <div type="trans">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">rajayoga</h3>
            Rājayoga is that by which longterm durability of the body arises even amongst manifold royal pleasures even amongst the manifold royal entertainments and spectacle. This truly is rājayoga. Of this [rājayoga] these are the
            varieties:
        </div>
    </div>
        <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-edition_1" class="edition">
        <div type="ed">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">intro1</h3>
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
                <p><mark>śrī gaṇeśāya namaḥ</mark> // <mark>atha rājayogaprakāro likhyate</mark> //</p>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">
                        śrī gaṇeśāya namaḥ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>
                        <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]
                    </span>
                    śrī ṇe ya maḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>), śrī gurave namaḥ (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a>), śrī sarasvatyai namaḥ śrī nirañjanāya namaḥ (<a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>), oṃ
                    śrī niraṃjanāya (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)
                </div>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">atha rājayogaprakāro likhyate (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>) ]</span> atha rājayogaprakāra likhyate (
                    <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>), rājayogāntargataḥ / binduyogaḥ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>), atha tattvabiṃduyogaprāraṃbhaḥ (<a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a>), atha rājayoga
                    liṣyate (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>), atha rājayoga likhyate (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div type="ed">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">rajayoga</h3>
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
                <p>rājayogasyedaṃ phalaṃ / yena rājayogenānekarājyabhogasamaya eva / anekapārthivavinoda<mark>prekṣaṇasamaya</mark> eva / bahutarakālaṃ śarīrasthitirbhavati / sa <mark>eva</mark> rājayogaḥ / tasyaite bhedāḥ /</p>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">prekṣaṇasamaya (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span>
                    prekṣyaṇasamaya (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)
                </div>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">eva (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> evaṃ (
                    <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-translation_1" class="translation">
        <div type="trans">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">intro1</h3>
            Homage to Śrī Gaṇeśa. Now the methods of rājayoga are laid down.
        </div>
        <div type="trans">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">rajayoga</h3>
            Rājayoga is that by which longterm durability of the body arises even amongst manifold royal pleasures even amongst the manifold royal entertainments and spectacle. This truly is rājayoga. Of this [rājayoga] these are the
            varieties:
        </div>
    </div>
     <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-edition_1" class="edition">
        <div type="ed">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">intro1</h3>
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
                <p><mark>śrī gaṇeśāya namaḥ</mark> // <mark>atha rājayogaprakāro likhyate</mark> //</p>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">
                        śrī gaṇeśāya namaḥ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>
                        <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]
                    </span>
                    śrī ṇe ya maḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>), śrī gurave namaḥ (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a>), śrī sarasvatyai namaḥ śrī nirañjanāya namaḥ (<a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>), oṃ
                    śrī niraṃjanāya (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)
                </div>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">atha rājayogaprakāro likhyate (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>) ]</span> atha rājayogaprakāra likhyate (
                    <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>), rājayogāntargataḥ / binduyogaḥ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>), atha tattvabiṃduyogaprāraṃbhaḥ (<a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a>), atha rājayoga
                    liṣyate (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>), atha rājayoga likhyate (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div type="ed">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">rajayoga</h3>
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
                <p>rājayogasyedaṃ phalaṃ / yena rājayogenānekarājyabhogasamaya eva / anekapārthivavinoda<mark>prekṣaṇasamaya</mark> eva / bahutarakālaṃ śarīrasthitirbhavati / sa <mark>eva</mark> rājayogaḥ / tasyaite bhedāḥ /</p>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">prekṣaṇasamaya (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span>
                    prekṣyaṇasamaya (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)
                </div>
                <div class="app">
                    <span class="lem">eva (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> evaṃ (
                    <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-translation_1" class="translation">
        <div type="trans">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">intro1</h3>
            Homage to Śrī Gaṇeśa. Now the methods of rājayoga are laid down.
        </div>
        <div type="trans">
            <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">rajayoga</h3>
            Rājayoga is that by which longterm durability of the body arises even amongst manifold royal pleasures even amongst the manifold royal entertainments and spectacle. This truly is rājayoga. Of this [rājayoga] these are the
            varieties:
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes pretty much! But not exactly yet. intro 1 translation and intro 1 edition needs to be in one raw. and rajayoga tanslation as well as rajayoga edition needs to be in one row.

Comment: I also updated the  question now a bit. Instead of type I figured out that I can also set the marker n="1" ... etc. I think its more clear in the updated formulation of my question. Sorry I lost concentration a bit. I feel like going nuts :)

Comment: Wow! Yeah! Exactly so. Only thing that is missing now would be a colored separation not just between the columns but also between the rows. Like the grid gap which is above between the columns dividing horzizontally, also a grid gap dividing vertically. How did you do that?

Comment: @NIlsJacob, I have updated the answer. Check please :)    I just inherited the grid rules and set `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;` for both selectors - `.edition` and `.translation`.

Comment: @NIlsJacob, Also, pay attention to the fact that the lines are not quite even in position - https://ibb.co/pWTdg6q. This is because in selector `.edition`, the text is wrapped in the `<p></p>` tag, while the selector `.translation` is not.

Comment: Thank you so much @s.kuznetsov. You are a magician. Do you like beer? I'd like to send you a sixpack of my favourite :)

Comment: I can wrap .translation up in <p></p> too.

Comment: I try now to put more of edition and more of translation and to see if it continues to work like this.

Comment: @NIlsJacob, Thanks for the offer and I appreciate it. But I quit drinking after the birth of my third daughter :)

Comment: @NIlsJacob, If you have any questions, I will answer with great pleasure :)

Comment: Super kool that you stopped drinking. Congrats. I also have two dauthers. This means only I need to stop when third comes. No anyway very inspiring not to drink anymore. I should do that, too. And thanks you for everything again! I will write here if anything weird crops up again! You saved my day!

Comment: Maybe one little more question. If I double the html with the same css the output is not changing. So the idea is actually to add more and more blocks with edition and translation. How can I add more rows?

Comment: @NIlsJacob, Which part of the html do you want to double?

Comment: Everything @s.kuznetsov that is nested in body. And basically not just once but infinitely. I want to use this css and this html to constantly add new rows of translation and edition. It is a very long text. But it seems not to work. If I double or trible it remains with just 2 rows.

Comment: @NIlsJacob, `.edition` and `.translation` - dynamic classes? Or maybe what's inside these classes is dynamic?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this question @s.kuznetsov. Sorry for me being so lamebrained. So what I want to do is to add more html and get many more rows. More pieces of edition and more pieces of translation. for example now we have intro1 -> translation - intro1 -> edition then comes rajayoga -> translation - rajayoga -> edition .... now I would for example add intro2 -> translation - intro2 -> edition - rajayoga2 translation - rajayoga2 edition and so on and so forth... like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906501/css-grid-vertical-columns-with-infinite-rows

Comment: Wow :) Now it is just perfect! You are a hero. You can't imagine how hard I tried.

Comment: @NIlsJacob, Thank you friend :) I tried. Can you mark my answer as solved?

Comment: Thank you Wizard @s.kuznetsov. This is my first question here. Where do I do this?

Comment: @NIlsJacob, Happy to help. If you have any questions, please let me know. Good luck :)

Comment: Dear @s.kuznetsov, I started adding new pieces of edition and translation. I put the most recent html code and your css with some editional css of me. Unfortunately if I add more edition and translation the respective edition and translation are not in alignment anymore, because they have very different length or footnotes or comments that need to be displayed as well. I UPDATED MY QUESTION ABOVE TO MAKE THE NEW PROBLEM VISIBLE. Do you see a chance to align them properly? Your help would be very appreciated again! Thanks and best wishes, Nils

Comment: Dear @s.kuznetsov, I just saw that I simply need to add  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; Then everything is aligned very nicely. However all boxes get exactly the same heigt. Is it prossible to get rid of the empty space for each row and still have it aligned on the same level?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228145/discussion-between-s-kuznetsov-and-nils-jacob).