# Why does a grid-area name absent in grid-template-areas create additional tracks?

Tags: css, css-grid

I've created a simple CSS Grid, I decided to not specify `grid-template`, `grid-template-columns`, `grid-template-rows` properties.

Instead, I started with `grid-template-areas`, and assigned *area names* to the *grid-items* via `grid-area` property.

After that, I was interested in what would happen if I remove *grid-item* from `grid-template-areas`. The result was kind of strange.

The removed *grid-item* was placed on the right and separated by *additional column.*

The problem: 
[image]

Why did this happen? Is this expected behaviour or did I miss something in my code? How can I remove this column?

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
     "header"
     "footer";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: lightblue;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: darkorange;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Posting a bounty for @TemaniAfif for an exceptionally well-researched and detailed answer. Additional answers are welcome and will be considered for a part of the bounty.

Comment: @Michael_B thanks :) but you also have done a big part of the work finding the culprit and that was the starting point of my answer ;)

Answer (score 19):

There are four parts to this answer. The first three help explain the fourth, which covers the reason for the extra column. If you're only interested in the answer, skip to the end.

Contents:

1. More than meets the eye: *There's also an extra row!*
2. The `grid-area` property.
3. The `grid-template-areas` property.
4. The placement of unreferenced grid areas.

---

### 1. More than meets the eye: *There's also an extra row!*

You've only partially defined the problem. Yes, there's an extra column. But there's also an extra row.

Because you haven't defined a height on the grid container, the height defaults to `auto` – the height of the content ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276)). So any rows with no content simply collapse and are invisible.

This issue doesn't exist with width because, in this case, you're using a block-level container (created by `display: grid`), which is designed to consume the full width of its parent, by default ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276)).

So that's why you're not seeing the extra row. If you give the container some height, the row will appear.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "footer";
  height: 150px; /* new */ 
}
```

[image]

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "footer";
  height: 150px; /* new */
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: aqua;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: darkorange;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

*Note: If you had used `display: inline-grid`, both the extra row and the extra column would have been invisible.*

```css
body {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "footer";
}
```

[image]

```css
body {
  display: inline-grid; /* adjustment */
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "footer";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: aqua;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: darkorange;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

---

### 2. The `grid-area` property.

Giving a name to the `grid-area` property creates a [named line](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#implicit-named-line) for each side of the area.

For example, `grid-area: header` resolves, in order, like this:

- `grid-row-start: header`
- `grid-column-start: header`
- `grid-row-end: header`
- `grid-column-end: header`

Like `margin`, `border` and `padding`, the [**`grid-area`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area) property is a shorthand property. Unlike those properties, `grid-area` has a counterclockwise resolution order (in LTR languages), as illustrated above.

Because named grid areas occupy space, they need rows and columns in which to exist. Hence, *named grid areas always impact the layout, even when they're not referenced in `grid-template-areas`*.

So all that is necessary to "fix" your layout is to remove `grid-area: main`.

```css
main {
  /* grid-area: main; */
  background: darkorange;
}
```

[image]

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "footer";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: aqua;
}

main {
  /* grid-area: main; */
  background: darkorange;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

---

### 3. The `grid-template-areas` property.

Rows and columns (a/k/a tracks) that are created using `grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-columns` or `grid-template-areas` belong to the *explicit grid*. Any tracks not defined by those properties belong to the *implicit grid* ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids)).

For every string listed in [**`grid-template-areas`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas), a new row is created.

For every name or sequence of dots (`...`) in the string, a new column is created (but this doesn't apply in this case because each string has only one name).

Your code creates an explicit grid with two rows and one column:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "footer";
}
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, `header` and `footer` have their own rows and exist in column one, exactly as defined in `grid-template-areas`.

The additional two rows and two columns are part of the implicit grid.

We can verify this by sizing them.

[`grid-template-columns`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing) works only on explicit columns.

[`grid-auto-columns`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#implicit-grids) works *mostly* on implicit columns (see note below).

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "footer";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns: 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-auto-rows: 25px;
}
```

[image]

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "footer";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns: 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-auto-rows: 25px;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: aqua;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: darkorange;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

*Note: If grid items are placed using `grid-template-areas` (creating explicit tracks), but they are not sized using `grid-template-columns` / `grid-template-rows`, then [`grid-auto-columns` / `grid-auto-rows` apply to them. <sup>(second paragraph)</sup>](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#explicit-grids)*

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "footer";
  grid-auto-columns: 100px;
  grid-auto-rows: 25px;
}
```

[image]

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "footer";
  grid-auto-columns: 100px;
  grid-auto-rows: 25px;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: aqua;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: darkorange;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

---

### 4. The placement of unreferenced grid areas.

*Note: To be perfectly honest, I'm about 75% sure this section is completely correct. The spec language was not 100% clear to me. I welcome feedback, corrections, and more accurate answers.*

In your code you have a third grid area which is not referenced in `grid-template-areas`.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "footer";
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: darkorange;
}
```

Where does `grid-area: main` go?

As we've already seen, it gets sent into the implicit grid, two columns and two rows in.

[image]

The grid area is handled by the [grid auto-placement algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement), which appears to say this:

1. Because `grid-area: main` isn't explicitly defined (see section 3 above), it belongs in the implicit grid.
2. Because grid column line 2 and grid row line 3 (the boundaries of the explicit grid) are named grid lines, new lines must be created in the implicit grid to accommodate the four named lines of `grid-area: main`. This can only happen with an empty row and empty column in between, separating the explicit grid from the auto-placed implicit grid area.

Comment: seems logical until I try this: https://jsfiddle.net/n7ja89zf/3/ ... following what you said we should not have overlap since the browser will try to avoid having named lines at the same line.

Comment: And even more surprising: https://jsfiddle.net/n7ja89zf/5/ .. I guess I will not watch my movie tonight.

Comment: At then end, you were on the good track and your explanation is coorect. I added an answer to better hightlight your points and show more examples about the *implicit lines*. It's a kind of step-by-step explanation until we reach the final result.

Comment: Interesting; I didn't know implicit grid track corners couldn't touch explicit grid track corners (assuming your last part is correct). Seems like a less-than-ideal design.

Comment: @TylerH actually they are touching because the middle empty column is inside the implicit grid. The trick is that an implicit line cannot be defined on the top of another explicit line so we will logically have an implicit track to separate them (the empty column)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, the overlap is confusing, too. I'm currently reading your answer (though I keep getting distracted...)

Comment: I made a small edit to my answer. I wasn't correct when explaining negative numbers. The element will not be placed above but the line will be generated above. The element is always placed below the line for any integer value (negative or positive).

Answer (score 13):

This is an extension to what [Michael_B already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57747781/8620333) in order to highlight how the implicit grid lines are created.

Let's start with an easy example:

```css
.container {
  width:100px;
  display: inline-grid;

  grid-auto-rows: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;

}
header {
  grid-row-start: header;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>H</header>
</div>
```

We have a grid item where we only set `grid-row-start` and the final result is two rows with an empty one. Both within the *implicit grid* since we didn't define any explicit one.

To understand what is happening let's refer to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid/):

> The three properties grid-template-rows, grid-template-columns, and grid-template-areas together define the explicit grid of a grid container. ... If these properties don’t define any explicit tracks the **explicit grid still contains one grid line in each axis**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids)</sup>

So even if we define nothing, we still have an explicit grid with two lines. This is very important because without those line we will not have our empty row.

Now the part explaining `grid-row-start:header`:

> `<custom-ident>`
>
> First attempt to match the grid area’s edge to a named grid area: if there is a named line with the name ''-start (for grid-*-start) / -end'' (for grid-*-end), contributes the first such line to the grid item’s placement.
>
> Otherwise, treat this as if the integer `1` had been specified along with the `<custom-ident>`.

It's clear that we will fall into the *otherwise* and will have `grid-row-start:header 1`:

> `<integer> && <custom-ident>?`
>
> Contributes the **Nth grid line** to the grid item’s placement...
>
> If a name is given as a `<custom-ident>`, only lines with that name are counted. If not **enough lines with that name exist, all implicit grid lines are assumed to have that name for the purpose of finding this position**.

In our case, we don't have enough lines with that name (we don't have any line at all) so we should add at least one line with that name and try to place our element, and since the integer is positive the item will be placed below that line:

[image]

The grid has a default line (red one), the use of `header` generates a new implicit one below it (due to the default value `1` added automatically), and the element will be placed below that line creating an extra row.

If we use `-1` will have only one row at the end:

```css
.container {
  width:100px;
  display: inline-grid;

  grid-auto-rows: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;

}
header {
  grid-row-start: header -1;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>H</header>
</div>
```

In this case the implicit line is generated **above** the explict one and our element placed between both lines.

> If a negative integer is given, it instead counts **in reverse**, starting from the **end edge of the explicit grid**.

[image]

The use of `-1` and `1` at the same time will give us the following result:

```css
.container {
  width:100px;
  display: inline-grid;

  grid-auto-rows: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;

}
header {
  grid-row-start: header -1;
  background: blue;
}

footer {
  grid-row-start: header 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>H</header>
  <footer>F</footer>
</div>
```

[image]

Here is another example with multiple items to illustrate that *all implicit grid lines are assumed to have that name*.

```css
.container {
  width:100px;
  display: inline-grid;

  grid-auto-rows: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;

}
header {
  grid-row-start: header 1;
  background: blue;
}
main {
  grid-row-start: main 1;
  background: red;
}
footer {
  grid-row-start: footer -1;
  background: green;
}
extra {
  grid-row-start: extra 5;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>H</header>
  <main>M</main>
  <footer>F</footer>
  <extra>E</extra>
</div>
```

In this example we need in total 6 implicit lines, because all the used integers are within the range `[-1,5]` (excluding `0` which is an invalid value), and, to place each element, all those lines will have the names defined for each element. That's why two elements with the same number will be in the same row (like `main` and `header`), since the reference line will be the same even with different names.

---

Now let's add `grid-row-end` to our previous example:

```css
.container {
  width:100px;
  display: inline-grid;

  grid-auto-rows: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;

}
header {
  grid-row-start: header;
  grid-row-end: header;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>H</header>
</div>
```

Nothing will happen and will have the exact same result because:

> If the start line is equal to the end line, remove the end line. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-placement-errors)</sup>

Let's use a different name:

```css
.container {
  width:100px;
  display: inline-grid;

  grid-auto-rows: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;

}
header {
  grid-row-start: header;
  grid-row-end: foo;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>H</header>
</div>
```

Still the same result because both are still equal (yes, they are equal!). Both values will be equal to `<name> 1`, so both will need only one implicit line. The browser will then create one implicit line that has two different names,  thus making both our values equal.

Let's change the value of one:

```css
.container {
  width:100px;
  display: inline-grid;

  grid-auto-rows: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;

}
header {
  grid-row-start: header 1;
  grid-row-end: foo 2;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>H</header>
</div>
```

Again the same result, but with "different" code. In this case, we will have 2 implicit lines and our element will be placed between them.

Basically the name is not relevant when it comes to implicit grid, because all of them will share the same lines. It's only relevant when we define them inside the explicit grid:

```css
.container {
  width:100px;
  display: inline-grid;

  grid-auto-rows: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;

}
header {
  grid-row-start: hello 1;
  grid-row-end: john 3;
  background: blue;
}
main {
  grid-row-start: main 1;
  grid-row-end: hi 2;
  background: red;
}
footer {
  grid-row-start: footer 2;
  grid-row-end: custom 5;
  background: green;
}
extra {
  grid-row-start: extra 3;
  grid-row-end: fsdfsdfsdfsd 5;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>H</header>
  <main>M</main>
  <footer>F</footer>
  <extra>E</extra>
</div>
```

In the above example, you can update the names with any random string and you will always have the same result; it only depends on the integer:

[image]

All the above will logically behave the same considering `grid-column-*`.

---

Now, we have everything we need to understand what is happening with the initial example.

First we have our explicit grid like below:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
     "header"
     "footer";
  /* No relevant but to better illustrate*/
  grid-auto-rows:50px;
  grid-auto-columns:50px;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: lightblue;
}

/*main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: darkorange;
}*/

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<!--<main>Main</main>-->
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

[image]

> The grid-template-areas property creates implicit named lines from the named grid areas in the template. For each named grid area foo, four implicit named lines are created: two named `foo-start`, naming the row-start and column-start lines of the named grid area, and two named `foo-end`, naming the row-end and column-end lines of the named grid area. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#implicit-named-lines)</sup>

Now if we add the third element with `grid-area:main;` it means we have

```css
grid-row-start:main 1;
grid-row-end:main 1;
grid-column-start:main 1;
grid-column-end:main 1;
```

We remove the `*-end` because they are equal to `*-start`

```css
grid-row-start:main 1
grid-column-start:main 1
```

Based on the previous explanation, we will need an extra implicit line called `main` and our element will be placed below the horizontal one and at the right of the vertical one:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
     "header"
     "footer";
  /* No relevant but to better illustrate*/
  grid-auto-rows:50px;
  grid-auto-columns:50px;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: lightblue;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: darkorange;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

[image]

If we remove the `grid-auto-*`, the rows will be the height of their content, making the row between `footer-end` and `main` empty. The column will split the width of grid element which is a block element have a full width. That's why you only see an extra column and not the extra row:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
     "header"
     "footer";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: lightblue;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: darkorange;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Another interesting observation is that if you add more elements with `grid-area:<name>`, they will all sit above each other:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
     "header"
     "footer";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: lightblue;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: darkorange;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: blue;
}

extra {
  grid-area: extra;
  background: red;
  opacity:0.8;
}
more {
  grid-area: more;
  background: green;
  opacity:0.3;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
<extra>E</extra>
<more>More</more>
```

Based on the previous explanation, all of them will have the following:

```css
grid-row-start:<name> 1;
grid-column-start:<name> 1;
```

Since the number is the same (the name is irrelevant as we already explained) they will all belong to the same area.

Comment: "Basically the name is not relevant when it comes to implicit grid because all of them will share the same lines. It's only relevant when we define them inside the explicit grid." Indeed, the name is not relevant *anywhere*, since names are just a user-friendly way to refer to the numerical value, which is the value the browser uses during grid creation. Focusing on names is a bit of a red herring.

Comment: @TylerH not really *anywhere*. They are relevant inside the explicit grid if you initially define grid-area or grid-line with an explicit name. In this case, the number will be irrelevant and the name will be relevant to find the position. Note in my answer the part that says "First attempt to match .." and if there is no match we will fall into the case where the browser will add the default integer `1`.