# Overiding CSS grid-template-columns individually

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create two buttons that each toggle a specific column when using CSS `grid`.

- I have a simply grid that toggles the width of first and last columns. *(See snippet)*
- I want to be able to toggle the column widths independantly *(Without further javascript)*.
- Because the `active` class is applied to the container each column cannot infer the active state of the other.
- With flex the active class would be applied to the column *(e.g `item1`)* directly making this a non issue.

**QUESTION**

Is there a CSS grid column width property that can be applied to a column *(e.g `item1`)* overiding the settings in `grid-template-columns`?

**OR**

Is there a CSS grid property like `grid-template-columns` that can target individual columns rather than all columns in one property?

```js
$("#js-btn-left").on("click", function () {
  $(".grid-container").toggleClass("active");
});
$("#js-btn-right").on("click", function () {
  $(".grid-container").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px auto 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: #b00;
  border:2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.grid-container.active{
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="js-btn-left" type="button" value="TOGGLE COLUMN 1"/>
<input id="js-btn-right" type="button" value="TOGGLE COLUMN 3"/>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: No...I don't believe that is possible. These aren't elements and so cannot be selected by JS or CSS. Parsing and adjusting the `template-columns` would be the way and that's complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the columns using CSS variables and then simply adjust the variable:

```js
$("#js-btn-left").on("click", function () {
  $(".grid-container").toggleClass("active1");
});
$("#js-btn-right").on("click", function () {
  $(".grid-container").toggleClass("active3");
});
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: var(--c1,50px) auto var(--c3,50px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: #b00;
  border:2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.grid-container.active1{
  --c1:100px;
}
.grid-container.active3{
  --c3:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="js-btn-left" type="button" value="TOGGLE COLUMN 1"/>
<input id="js-btn-right" type="button" value="TOGGLE COLUMN 3"/>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div> 
</div>
```

Another *hacky* way is to rely on the implicit grid and adjust `grid-auto-column`

```js
$("#js-btn-right").on("click", function () {
  $(".grid-container").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  auto ; /* only one column on the explicit grid */
  grid-auto-flow:column; /*Make the flow column*/
  grid-auto-columns:50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item1 {
   /* Make the item1 at the left of the explicit grid 
       to undestand how it works: 
       https://stackoverflow.com/a/57750033/8620333 */
  grid-column: random -1; 
}
.grid-container.active{
  grid-auto-columns:100px;
}



.grid-container > div {
  background-color: #b00;
  border:2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="js-btn-right" type="button" value="TOGGLE COLUMN"/>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div> 
</div>
```

If you want to target only one column:

```js
$("#js-btn-right").on("click", function () {
  $(".grid-container").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px auto ;
  grid-auto-flow:column; 
  grid-auto-columns:50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-container.active{
  grid-auto-columns:100px;
}



.grid-container > div {
  background-color: #b00;
  border:2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="js-btn-right" type="button" value="TOGGLE COLUMN"/>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div> 
</div>
```

---

Or instead of changing the column width you can simply change the number of column each item should take:

```js
$("#js-btn-left").on("click", function () {
  $(".grid-container").toggleClass("active1");
});
$("#js-btn-right").on("click", function () {
  $(".grid-container").toggleClass("active3");
});
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 40px auto 40px 50px; /* 40px because we have 10px of gap so the total will be 100px */
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: #b00;
  border:2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.item2 {
  grid-column:span 3;
}
.grid-container.active3 .item3,
.grid-container.active3 .item2,
.grid-container.active1 .item1,
.grid-container.active1 .item2{
  grid-column:span 2;
}

.grid-container.active1.active3 .item2{
  grid-column:initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="js-btn-left" type="button" value="TOGGLE COLUMN 1"/>
<input id="js-btn-right" type="button" value="TOGGLE COLUMN 3"/>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good idea that I will proberly use but I am curious if grid can achieve a similar effect.

Comment: @DreamTeK you cannot simply set the width of the element and keep the template set to auto? like that you simply change the width of the element and the grid will adjust automatically

Comment: @DreamTeK added another idea

Comment: I didn't know about auto columns. Good addition to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @DreamTeK added a third idea ;)

Comment: That's pretty clever. And some people say it wasn't possible :)