# Css grid repeat syntax

Tags: css, css-grid

I have to render a row using the css grid such that, the first column has to have a flexible length whereas all the rest of the columns have to have a fixed width. Something along the lines of the following

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(10, 100px)
```

The above does not work. How can this be done?

Comment: Why not use flex for this ? it's far too simple using flex, `flex:1` on the first item and a fixed width on the rest

Comment: related (probably a duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/a/58476744/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grid-template-columns: max-content repeat(4, 100px);`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content repeat(4, 100px);
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet...more</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="container">
  <div>1fr</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
</div>

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(10, 100px);
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `auto-fit`. It will fit the column into currently available space.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```