# Make grid rows optional

Tags: css, css-grid

I created a grid template and wanted to make the first row optional (area: "t").

If it's hidden, the auto row should fill the remaining height. I tried it with **minmax()** css function but it doesn't work.

```
grid-template:
 "t t t t" minmax(0px, 40px)
 "h h h h" 40px
 "s l m r" auto
 "s f f f" 57px / 200px 100px auto 100px;
```

Here is a fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/nzaj8102/

I managed to get it working by creating two template classes. I was wondering, if I can do it differently ?

```
.template-with-top{
    grid-template:
      "t t t t" 40px
      "h h h h" 40px
      "s l m r" auto
      "s f f f" 57px / 200px 100px auto 100px;
 }


  .template-without-top{
    grid-template:
      "h h h h" 40px
      "s l m r" auto
      "s f f f" 57px  / 200px 100px auto 100px;
    }

  .template-without-top > div:nth-child(1) {
     display:none
   }
```

Here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/hveu5bfc/

THX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your `minmax(0px, 40px)` idea makes sense, it doesn't work because not everything in grid makes sense. The fact is that [the `minmax()` function defaults to *max*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50654400/3597276), meaning that the row will be 40px tall even when there's no content inside.

Try this:

- Instead of using `minmax()` on the first row (`t t t t`), set it to `auto`, so it takes the height of the content.
- Instead of using `auto` on the third row (`s l m r`), set it to `1fr`, so it will consume all extra height in the container when the first row has no content.
- Control the height of the first row at the grid item level.

```css
.app-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template:
    "t t t t" auto
    "h h h h" 40px
    "s l m r" 1fr
    "s f f f" 57px;
}

.app-grid > div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-grid">
  <div style="grid-area: t; height: 40px; display: none;">t</div>
  <div style="grid-area: h;">h</div>
  <div style="grid-area: s;">s</div>
  <div style="grid-area: l;">l</div>
  <div style="grid-area: m;">m</div>
  <div style="grid-area: r;">r</div>
  <div style="grid-area: f;">f</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dx1fuc5h/)

Comment: THX!! super weird with minmax function :(

Comment: Thanks - just applied this to an item that only appears at small screen sizes..