# How to make auto grid with minmax of fixed size?

Tags: css, grid

Begin from such a grid:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

It works, but the `1fr` is a bit out of control. I want to limit it to some fixed value, say, `150px`:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 150px));
```

But it doesn't work, the columns are not elastic any more, always have width of 150px, see this demo:

```css
my-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 150px));
  grid-gap: 16px;
}

my-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<my-container>
  <my-block></my-block>
  <my-block></my-block>
  <my-block></my-block>
  <my-block></my-block>
  <my-block></my-block>
  <my-block></my-block>
  <my-block></my-block>
  <my-block></my-block>
  <my-block></my-block>
</my-container>
```

How to make it work, so that when I stretch the container, the column would get wider but not more than `150px`, until there is space to add a new column into the grid?

Comment: max-width: 150px to the grid item?

Comment: @TemaniAfif that would break the grid gap since there are more space inside a column than item.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50654400/3597276