# Make grid items fill columns not rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want my grid to fill in vertically:

```
1 4 7 
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Instead of it fills in horizontally:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

**In my grid I want to specify the number of columns, not the number of rows.**

This is what my div looks:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Initially, the grid lays out items in a horizontal direction. This is because an initial setting of a grid container is [**`grid-auto-flow: row`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property).

That's what you're getting in your layout:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row; /* default setting; can be omitted */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

If you switch to `grid-auto-flow: column`, then the grid items are laid out vertically.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

But for the row behavior in the vertical axis you need to define rows.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: 25px 25px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

*From the spec:*

> [**7.7. Automatic Placement: the `grid-auto-flow` property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property)
>
> This property controls how the auto-placement algorithm works, specifying exactly how auto-placed items get flowed into the grid.
>
> ***`row`***
>
> The auto-placement algorithm places items by filling each row in turn,
>   adding new rows as necessary. If neither `row` nor `column` is
>   provided, `row` is assumed.
>
> ***`column`***
>
> The auto-placement algorithm places items by filling each column in
>   turn, adding new columns as necessary.

For an alternative solution to CSS Grid, which doesn't require specifying the number of rows, try CSS Columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44099977/3597276