# Vertical alignment in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to use CSS grids to vertically align an unordered list. I am getting something like this:

```
*A*******
*B      *
*C*******
*********
*       *
*********
*********
*       *
*********
```

As you see grid template rows are made correctly but list items don't get placed in them properly. I've searched for this problem but I got no results(most of "griddings" were done using methods other than CSS Grid).

```css
.aside{
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(200,30,140,0.5);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,50px);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.aside ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

.aside ul li:nth-child(1){
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background-color:white;
}

.aside ul li:nth-child(2){
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background-color:cyan;
}

.aside ul li:nth-child(3){
  grid-row: 3/4;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="aside">
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that grid container properties only work between parent and child elements.

So, in your code, if the grid container is the `.aside` element, then your grid item properties will not work on the `li` elements: they are descendants beyond the children (grandchildren, in this case) and, therefore, out of scope.

The grid item is the `ul`.

Instead, try something like this:

```css
aside {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,50px);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</aside>
```

More information:

- [Make grid container fill columns not rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44092529/3597276)
- [Proper use of flex properties when nesting flex containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37840646/3597276) (applies to grid layout, as well)