# How do I make a 2 column layout where items starts from top to bottom (not left to right)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Essentially what I want to do is to have this kind of layout:

```
"item-1" "item-5"

"item-2" "item-6"

"item-3" "item-7"

"item-4"
```

Please notice that items go from top to bottom and not from left to right.

**EDIT:** It is unknown how many items are in the list

Comment: There’s a fuller discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/q/50693793/4711754

Answer (score 2):

Try CSS Multi-column Layout

```css
.column {
  -webkit-column-count: 2; 
  -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 40px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <p>item-1</p>
  <p>item-2</p>
  <p>item-3</p>
  <p>item-4</p>
  <p>item-5</p>
  <p>item-6</p>
  <p>item-7</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this seems to be working. The issue I have now is that if I have a multiline text the half of it gets cut and appear on the 2nd column. How can I make sure that it doesn't get cut? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link, as it says in the picture, you can choose, how the grid apears for you by rearranging items.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid_item.asp

[image: W3school Grid]

Answer (score -1):

If you know about div and inline-block, try making two divisions under a main div and give the display: inline-block property.
In this way you can easily set the margin and dimensions according to your need. 
This should solve your problem.