# Div alignment in html and css

Tags: html, css

I tried this html and CSS ,

```css
.divcss{
    width: 48%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="divcss"> Div1
</div>
<div class="divcss"> Div2
</div>
<div class="divcss"> Div3
</div>
<div class="divcss"> Div4
</div>
<div class="divcss"> Div5
</div>
<div class="divcss"> Div6
</div>

</div>
```

It's not compulsory to only 6 div's, it comes dynamically

I want to align div in this order:-

Div1       Div4

Div2       Div5

Div3       Div6

Comment: read about `columns`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried but fails :(

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50694753/746736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a additional class to your parent div, defining the column layout.

CSS:

```
.divcss {
width: 48%;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
}

.layout {
 columns: 2;
 height: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="layout">
  <div class="divcss"> Div1 </div>
  <div class="divcss"> Div2 </div>
  <div class="divcss"> Div3 </div>
  <div class="divcss"> Div4 </div>
  <div class="divcss"> Div5 </div>
  <div class="divcss"> Div6 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It solves my problem in an easier way. Thanks a lot @Sasi Kumar M

Answer (score 1):

Check this. Hope it helps.

```css
.columns{
    width: 50%;
    /*vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;*/
    float: left;
}
.divcss{
display:block;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="columns">
<div class="divcss"> Div1
</div>
<div class="divcss"> Div2
</div>
<div class="divcss"> Div3
</div>
</div>
<div class="columns">
<div class="divcss"> Div4
</div>
<div class="divcss"> Div5
</div>
<div class="divcss"> Div6
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just gotta make two columns or even just one, and put your content in them/it i like to make two to give each column a style.

```css
<style>
.divcss{
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.rcolumn {
    float:left;
}

.lcolumn {
    float:left;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="lcolumn">
 <div class="divcss"> Div1
 </div>
 <div class="divcss"> Div2
 </div>
 <div class="divcss"> Div3
 </div>
</div>

 <div class="rcolumn">
 <div class="divcss"> Div4
 </div>
 <div class="divcss"> Div5
 </div>
 <div class="divcss"> Div6
 </div>    
</div>
```