# How to make a CSS grid wrap automatically if the templates are set for columns and rows?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have 12 children `div`s in my `.wrapper` element that I'd like to stack next to each other. The number 12 is actually dynamic so I have no idea how many children I'll have. Right now my grid layout looks like this:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

This is fine until the grid should start wrapping the elements (the layout is full, the grid is 3x2 which holds 6 elements). The seventh, eigth and all of the rest are stacked next to the first six, although I would want them to be in a new line with the same template (so essentially my grid would become 2x(3x2)).

The explanation probably doesn't make too much sense on its own, check out the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKVYzO) as well.

How do I make the elements after the sixth one wrap into a new line?

Comment: In the default `grid-auto-flow: row` direction, you use `repeat`, `minmax` and `auto-fill` / `auto-fit`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKgONG

Comment: With `grid-auto-flow: column`, there are obstacles: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44092529/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Nope, this makes One and Two stack next to each other instead of under each other. The first column should be One, Two, Seven, Eight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use auto flow to form grid (like @vals's answer suggests) and then set the pattern in which order it should be populated via set of `:nth-child()` rules:

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #f76707;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff4e6;
}

.wrapper > div {
    border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffd8a8;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #d9480f;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper > :nth-child(6n + 1),
.wrapper > :nth-child(6n + 2) {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.wrapper > :nth-child(6n + 3),
.wrapper > :nth-child(6n + 4) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.wrapper > :nth-child(6n + 5),
.wrapper > :nth-child(6n + 6) {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
  <div>Eight</div>
  <div>Nine</div>
  <div>Ten</div>
  <div>Eleven</div>
  <div>Twelve</div>
  
  <div>Thirteen</div>      
  <div>Fourteen</div>      
  <div>And so on</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This grid stuff is magical, but the solution that vals proposed and you perfected works! Thanks! I chose this as the correct answer because I needed the grid to work for n+1 elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use grid-auto-flow: row. And then you need to set a special rule for items 2 and 4, just setting the row will be enough.

I have removed the grid-templated-rows: auto property, it's the default, and it's not needed if you position the elements this way.

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #f76707;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff4e6;
}

.wrapper > div {
    border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffd8a8;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #d9480f;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(-2n + 4) {
  grid-row: 2;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
  <div>Eight</div>
  <div>Nine</div>
  <div>Ten</div>
  <div>Eleven</div>
  <div>Twelve</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks that OP wants the items in each 3x2 subpattern to go in columns. If so, special rules for 2 items would be not sufficient, the `:nth-child` selectors will need to specify the whole pattern, like ```.wrapper > :nth-child(6n + 1),
.wrapper > :nth-child(6n + 2) {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.wrapper > :nth-child(6n + 3),
.wrapper > :nth-child(6n + 4) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.wrapper > :nth-child(6n + 5),
.wrapper > :nth-child(6n + 6) {
  grid-column: 3;
}```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I changed the value of `grid-auto-flow` from `column dense` to **`row dense`**.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #f76707;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff4e6;
}

.wrapper > div {
    border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffd8a8;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #d9480f;
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div>Five</div>
    
    <div>Six</div>
    <div>Seven</div>
    <div>Eight</div>
    <div>Nine</div>
    <div>Ten</div>
    <div>Eleven</div>
    <div>Twelve</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This still stacks One and Two next to each other, not underneath each other. The first column should be One, Two, Seven, Eight, etc, etc...