# Why do CSS Grid items not wrap if container has no defined height?

Tags: css, css-grid, grid-layout

I have a list of items in a grid layout and the grid container has a width set, but no height set.

I want the items to populate columns until it hits the container width, then wrap into rows.

But right now I can only get it to work that way if define a height on the container.

Below is a snippet.

The grid items never wrap unless you uncomment the `height` rule for the container, but I want the container grow/shrink to fit after the grid wraps.

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  /*   height: 500px; */
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the items to populate columns until it hits the container width, then wrap into rows.

Then why are you using `grid-auto-flow: column` and `grid-template-rows`?

With `grid-auto-flow: column` the grid items will flow vertically, filling rows then creating new columns. You're saying you want the reverse: fill columns, then create new rows. So stick with the default, `grid-auto-flow: row`.

Along the same lines, switch from `grid-template-rows` to `grid-template columns`. You want to auto fill columns, not rows.

No height is necessary on the grid container.

In fact, you don't need a width or height on the items either.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

More details: [Make grid container fill columns not rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44092529/3597276)