# Render parent <ul> list in columns (display: grid vs. column-count: 3). Either I get wrong order or weird shape of child <ul>

Tags: html, css

OK, so what I need is to render nested `ul` / `li` into 3 columns.

**I want to do this with pure CSS (and no JS)** and I have 2 semi-working examples.

**Example 1 via `display: grid`** https://jsfiddle.net/slick/1rtucfmL/2/

So for parent `ul` you simply specify `display: grid` with `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr` and you have 3 columns. When you hover on item, then child `ul` renders nicely.

[image]

This example however has issue where **items are rendered horizontally** (don't want that):

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

**rather than** vertically (this is what I need):

```
a d g 
b e h
c f i
```

[Someone asked this before and the solution is to define qty. of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092529/make-grid-container-fill-columns-not-rows). I can't do this because I have dynamic quantity of rows and I don't want to hardcode any values.

So I went to the second example…

**Example 2 via `column-count: 3`** https://jsfiddle.net/slick/g5p2j8bo/2/

This renders column items as I want, from A to Z vertically. However the issue is that when you hover on item, the child `ul` is shown in a very bizarre way (sometimes it's broken into columns as well, I don't want this).

[image]

If only I could fix this child positioning then example 2 would suit my needs.

I have no idea why this happens. I tried to set `column-count: 1` because I thought that maybe it inherits `3` from parent but that didn't help.

Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something that can help is avoid breaks, so your css code should be like this

```
ul#root li>ul {
  top: -12px;
  left: 190px;
  position: absolute;
  break-inside: avoid;  // added
  page-break-inside: avoid;  // added
  will-change: transform;  // added
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  list-style: none;
  width: 190px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .02em;
}
```

Couldn't add snippet because body limit, but [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MSclavi/qn6he39r/1/).

Comment: Hi @MSclavi, thanks for your reply. This looks like a step in a good direction however still some child `ul` elements are positioned in a weird way.

Answer (score 0):

Use MSclavi's solution, along with `display: inline-block`.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o47z8f6e/)

```
ul#root li>ul {
  top: -12px;
  left: 190px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  break-inside: avoid; 
  page-break-inside: avoid;  
  will-change: transform; 
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  list-style: none;
  width: 190px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .02em;
}
```

This is one of the most frustrating problems that I've encountered in CSS3, but!

Try using flex columns with a static height.

```
ul#root {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 16em; /* Static heights! Oh no! */
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/bny1e3r6/1/)

Comment: That indeed helps a bit, but unfortunately I can roughly predict quantity of item and if the height is not big enough, items will create `4th` column, while `3` is max. I can allow.

Comment: @MattKomarnicki Yeah, I get it.

Comment: @MattKomarnicki Okay...how about now?