# Fixed number of columns, ordered top-bottom left-right

Tags: css

I want (if possible) to make a css trick to create 3 columns,
ascending order, from top to bottom and left to right. I would rather show with examples what I want to achieve:

> For

```
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
</div>
```

I would like to see this order:

```
1 4 6
2 5 7
3
```

> For

```
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

I would like to see this order:

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

> For

```
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

I would like to see:

```
1 3 5
2 4
```

> For

```
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

I would like to see:

```
1 3 4
2
```

> For

```
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

I would like to see:

```
1 2 3
```

> For

```
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
</div>
```

I would like to see:

```
1 2
```

And so on. I was thinking to use flex columns but could make to match the pattern above.
So I used Javascript to order the columns and achieve the desired effect. But some folks claim it could be achieved as well using CSS `flexbox.

Comment: Can't be done using flexbox because of the way you have the gap below 5 on the first one and 3 when you only have 4. It may be possible with grid, but not sure as I haven't used it that much

Comment: you can almost have this with column: https://jsfiddle.net/ytw6mb2c/

Comment: Find similar example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092529/make-grid-container-fill-columns-not-rows

Comment: @TemaniAfif I know you can answer this question:)