# How to split menu in two columns with different auto width?

Tags: html, css

I have menu with dynamic number of elements:

```
<ul>
  <li>Link with long text 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
  <li>Link 4</li>
  <li>Link 5</li>
  <li>Link 6</li>
  <li>Link 7</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to split it in 2 top to bottom columns with auto width height:

[image]

I tried to use `columns`, but both column widths are 50%, even though second column in my example doesn't need to be that big. As a result, menu can't be visually centered.

```
ul {
  display: block;
  column-gap: 40px;
  columns: 2;
}
li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Then I tried to use `grid`. It gives me what I want except that I have to explicitly state how many rows I want. Is there a way to state that I want the amount of rows to be equal to half of elements?

```
ul {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px 40px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

Comment: I find it strange that my queston was closed even though in the end of its description I switched to CSS grid instead of columns.

Comment: That is because there is no definitive answer to this question. Check this out!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092529/make-grid-container-fill-columns-not-rows