# How to make two columns with CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an array of N elements:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
```

I need to make two columns in following order:

If we have 10 elements:

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
```

If we have 9 elements:

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5
```

If we have 7 elements:

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
4
```

And so on. CSS should devide elements into two columns.

The number of elements isn't a constant.

The code in react is pretty simple:

```
numList.map(item => (
            <div>{item}</div>
          ))
```

I can devide elements array into two arrays using js and then render it as two list separatelly and make columns for it with flex.

But I wish to know if there a way to do it with CSS only without JS.

How do I make two columns with CSS?

Comment: Have you read some tutorials? maybe grid or flexbox..... I'll suggest to try something

Comment: try with <tr><td> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp#:~:text=The%20element%20defines%20a,%2C%20and%20elements.

Comment: @Sfili_81 the problem is that the number of columns isn't constant.

Comment: @FaroukMhamdi the problem is that the number of columns isn't constant.

Comment: yeah it's ok work with looping the array of data

Comment: put your code here i will help you

Comment: @FaroukMhamdi use table for layout isn't a good idea, it can be achieved with grid, but we have poor information about OP code

Comment: yes , i told him to share the code here

Comment: @FaroukMhamdi  I've added some details. I know how to split the elements array into two arrays with js and then I may use grid or flex to render it separatelly. But I wish to know if there a way to do it with CSS only?

Comment: @Sfili_81 I've added some details. I know how to split the elements array into two arrays with js and then I may use grid or flex to render it separatelly. But I wish to know if there a way to do it with CSS only?

Comment: Before asking have you tried something? maybe search on google _How do I make two columns with CSS?_ Or searching here on SO....

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092529/make-grid-container-fill-columns-not-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092529/make-grid-container-fill-columns-not-rows) for example....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your examples, I think just a simple `columns: 2` would have this functionality.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  columns: 2;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid-template-columns property and specifies the number (and the widths) of columns in a grid layout. The values are a space separated list, where each value specifies the size of the respective column.

Refer this: [CSS Grid Layout Module](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px 20px;
}
```

For this example, I specified each column only 20px width, you can put your own numbers or auto for the width.
You can also use repeat function to repeat same pattern of column multiple of times. For example:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 50px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to give class to parent div and give display as grid and in column give how many element you want in one column

```
.container{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr)}

<div class="container">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```