# Set "max rows" in grid-template-rows: repeat()

Tags: css, css-grid

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 2em);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  column-gap: 1em;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
</ul>
</hr>
```

In this code I have a list with `grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 2em);`.

This fills the first column until the fourth row and then starts the second column.
This is good.

The problem I have is that, when I have less than 4 items, the grid is still 4 rows tall.
Is there a way to make the grid grow until the fourth row and then start adding columns?

Something like `grid-template-rows: repeat(max 4, 2em)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not naturally (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092529/make-grid-container-fill-columns-not-rows)).

You can cheat though by defining a maximum number of rows and setting the height of the rows to `auto` and moving the *actual* height definition to the `li`. See [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/abXJLeL).

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  column-gap: 1em;
  row-gap: 0.25em;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 1.2em;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
</ul>
</hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like below:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 2em; /* height of one row */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  column-gap: 1em;
}

/* define explict positions and stop at row 4 */
ul li:nth-child(4n + 1) {grid-row: 1}
ul li:nth-child(4n + 2) {grid-row: 2}
ul li:nth-child(4n + 3) {grid-row: 3}
ul li:nth-child(4n + 4) {grid-row: 4}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>X</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Y</li>
</ul>
<hr>
```