# Rearranging items based on width

Tags: html, css

I have a list of let's say 20 items. on the desktop side of things i would like to order them like this:

```
1     6      11      16
2     7      12      17
3     8      13      18
4     9      14      19 
5     10     15      20
```

on the tablet side i would like to change it up to:

```
1      8          15
2      10         16
...    ...        20
7      14
```

and on the mobile view

```
1            11
2            12
...          ...
10           20
```

Is this doable pure html/css ? I feel like it isn't ...

Comment: Do you have exactly 20 elements, or would this have to be dynamic, to also fit more elements? So the amount of columns are important to you right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44099977/383904