How to have dynamic rows when using grid-auto-flow: column?
It seems it just didn't fully understand the css grid mechanics. So here I am:


ul{
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  max-width: 888px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Aziende agricole</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dove mangiare</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dove dormire</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Botteghe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">La Molonara</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">I Stròdi</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">La Tèra crèa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Eventi</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Didattica</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
</ul>



As you can see, it works, but apparently I have to define a fixed number of rows. And if I have more elements, another column will be created instead of another row.
Is there a way to solve, other than using grid-auto-flow: row? I'm using column because I need that items distribution, like:
Aziende agricole
Dove mangiare
Dove dormire

And not
Aziende agricole    Dove mangiare    Dove dormire


I don't quite understand what you expect from this code? What do you want to happen that isn't happening?

@AgotaKristof I edited my question so it will be more clear.

Not with Css-grid. Sounds like you need column count

@Paulie_D it was the 1st thing I tried, but then I loosed horizontal aligning.

Do you mean something like this?:
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: auto;
max-width: 888px;
margin: 0 auto;
}```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092529/make-grid-container-fill-columns-not-rows?rq=1

According to my knowledge grid row only works when we specify a fixed height. You can remove grid-auto-flow : columns in order to maintain three columns even when elements increase.
