# Moving <li> to next column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following html code:

```
<div style="column-count: 3;">
    <ul>
        <li><h3>Education<h3></li>
        <li><a>Education 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Education 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Education 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><h3>Careers<h3></li>
        <li><a>Careers1</a></li>
        <li><a>Careers2</a></li>
        <li><a>Careers3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><h3>Legal<h3></li>
        <li><a>Legal</a></li>
        <li><a>Legal</a></li>
        <li><a>Legal</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It divides the `ul`'s into 3 columns. The following picture explains above code:

[image]

As you can see, `Education` is at the bottom of the first column, it looks weird because it's subsequent anchor tags are moved to the next column. I want to move `Education` to the next column as well in such case. Any CSS or JS solution?

Comment: I have tried this div ul {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: auto; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    page-break-inside: auto; /* Firefox */
    break-inside: auto; /* IE 10+ */
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
   float:left;
}

Comment: Why none of those <a> are closed? Some of <a> start in one <li> and finish in the other. What's going on here?

Comment: Don't paste code to the comment section, edit your question, and add you code there.

Comment: why don't you use blank ```li``` there? ```<li></li>``` this can also work try it

Comment: Actually problem is none of the `<a>` are closed. it should be closed with `</a>`

Comment: @AlivetoDie The actual problem is that he asks for a CSS or JS solution of moving a html element. I would really love to see a CSS that can do that.

Comment: This is an incorrect usage of a list item and that is the cause of this issue. Your heading element will be treated the same as the other list items. You need to rethink your layout and put them all in a sectioning element instead.

Comment: Actually this is the dynamic code i am getting via service. Can't do anything @Rob.

Comment: With CSS you can do this https://jsfiddle.net/ppcfL7sg/ ... but you can't explicit only target _if_ the header is the last, as there is no _last-child-in-column_ property. For that it takes a script.

Answer (score 0):

A less-than-semantic but effective solution as inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785374/how-to-prevent-column-break-within-an-element) is to wrap each `h3` and the following `a` in an element, and then set them to `display: inline-block`.

We have to add some extra styles to make the list appear "normal" and not as a nested list, but this will effectively prevent a header from hanging at the bottom of any column. If one of the divs wrapping an `h3` and the `a` immediately after it would normally break across columns, the use of `display: inline-block` on its children (i.e., the `h3` and `a`) will prevent that break.

```css
/* the important part */
ul li ul li div h3,
ul li ul li div a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* aesthetics */
ul li ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul li ul li {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
div {
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div style="column-count: 3;">
  <ul>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <h3>Education</h3>
            <a>Education 1</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Education 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Education 3</a></li>
    <li><a>Education 4</a></li>
    <li><a>Education 5</a></li>
    <li><a>Education 6</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <h3>Careers</h3>
            <a>Careers1</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Careers2</a></li>
    <li><a>Careers3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <h3>Legal</h3>
            <a>Legal</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Legal</a></li>
    <li><a>Legal</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Compare against:

```css
/* the important part */
/*ul li ul li div h3,
ul li ul li div a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}*/


/* aesthetics */
ul li ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul li ul li {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
div {
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div style="column-count: 3;">
  <ul>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <h3>Education</h3>
            <a>Education 1</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Education 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Education 3</a></li>
    <li><a>Education 4</a></li>
    <li><a>Education 5</a></li>
    <li><a>Education 6</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <h3>Careers</h3>
            <a>Careers1</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Careers2</a></li>
    <li><a>Careers3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <h3>Legal</h3>
            <a>Legal</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Legal</a></li>
    <li><a>Legal</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*(Note: The above snippets fix a problem you had with not closing your `h3` tags correctly.)*

Answer (score -2):

If you are using bootstrap, you can set put each list in a div and assign a col-xs-4 class to each div.  If not, you can emulate something like the grid system.

Comment: Based on what the OP is requesting, they only care about the actual display and not functionally moving it.  CSS can do this.

Comment: They are only asking for this because "Education" ends up at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Are you able to assign css to html that comes back?  Have you tried adding display:flex to the parent div?