# Chromium update (Chrome and Edge 108) broke my Javascript that posts data to a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

With the latest Chrome/Edge update (108) my page now hangs instead of showing the data in the modal. I get a unresponsive error and it never resolves. Sometimes the modal footer shows but never the data. If I downgrade my Chrome version it resolves the issue. Am I doing something wrong here that I can correct?

Modal on the main page:

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body" style="column-count: 3; column-width: 100px; margin: auto">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" name="Save" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> DocumentTypes(int id)
{
   //Code to populate the model
   return PartialView("_DocumentTypes", model);
}
```

Javascript:

```
function documentTypeSelect(id) {
  $.get("@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")/" + id,
    function (data) {
      $('.modal-body').html(data);
    });
    $("#documentTypeModel").modal("show");
}
```

Button that fires the Javascript:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="white-space: normal; text-align: left" id="@item.Id" onclick="documentTypeSelect(this.id)">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.DocuType)
</a>
```

**Edit:**

Rendered Javascript:

```
function documentTypeSelect(id) {
  $.get("/Controller/Method/" + id,
    function (data) {
      $('.modal-body').html(data);
    });
    $("#documentTypeModel").modal("show");
}
```

If I comment out the following code in my Javascript the modal shows and there is no unresponsive error, but obviously the data in the modal-body doesn't show.

```
$('.modal-body').html(data);
```

PartialView where I am rendering the list I created in the controller:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.DocumentTypeList.Count(); i++)
{
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="form-group col-md">
      <div class="row row-eq-height border-bottom">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DocumentTypeList[i].Display, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DocumentTypeList[i].Status, new { @class = "form-control" })
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DocumentTypeList[i].Display)
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DocumentTypeList[i].Code)
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

**Edit 2:**

If I remove this styling then the modal displays without Chrome hanging.

```
<div class="modal-body" style="column-count: 3; column-width: 100px; margin: auto">
```

**Edit 3:**

If I only remove **margin: auto**, then it works as well...like so:

```
<div class="modal-body" style="column-count: 3; column-width: 100px;">
```

Comment: anything relevant in the debugging console log?

Comment: What is the _rendered_ javascript?

Comment: @stuartd

Nothing

Comment: @JoelPeltonen

I added the rendered Javascript to my post

Comment: ` $.get("/Controller/Method/" + id,` this cant be correct, unless you're obfuscating the controller class name and method name for some reason.

Comment: @d0rf47
I am obfuscating it. Force of habit.

Comment: Hm. Extremely weird. Could it be an outright bug in chrome? Someone else reported weird behavior as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457560/strange-behavior-of-the-column-count-property-in-chrome

Comment: Kinda in any case sounds like it's a purely frontend/browser thing

Comment: @JoelPeltonen

It does feel like either a bug in Chrome or some functionality that was deprecated in Chrome 108. We primarily use Chrome and this code has been in production for a few months with no issues until Chrome 108.

Comment: We were recently notified by a client affected by this same issue, which I recently tracked down to the `column-count` property. This is now broken in Chrome 108 when the site went live in February of this year and has been running without issues. Replacing this with `display: flex` to achieve the column effect works, but unfortunately with the items in a different order which isn't ideal. I've opened a Chromium issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1400279

Comment: @jrrdnx Thanks, glad it's not just me. I'll keep an eye on the issue you created!

Comment: @jrrdnx Are you still seeing the issue? I just tried it again on 108 and I'm not seeing it anymore. Not sure if they made a change. Version 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @StealthGhost Confirmed the old column-count code that I was seeing with this issue in 108.0.5359.98 is now working for me in 108.0.5359.124.