# CSS: keep the blocks inseparable when passing to a new column

Tags: css

I have the following ([codepen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/GdjjbR))

```css
.container{column-count:2; width: 50%; border: 1px solid;}
.entry{border: 1px dotted red;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="entry">
    <h3>header 1</h3>
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <h3>header 1</h3>
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <h3>header 1</h3>
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <h3>header 1</h3>
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <h3>header 1</h3>
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

is there a way to keep the "red" blocks to be inseparable? I mean, pass to the second column entirely, as a  whole block?

[image]

Comment: @Terry unfortunately the "duplicate" solutions don't solve the problem...

Comment: Yes it does, as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17415553/395910. Apply it to the `.entry` element, not the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `display: inline-block` to the entry class should work.
CSS:

```
.container{
  column-count: 2; 
  width: 50%; 
  border: 1px solid;
}
.entry{
  border: 1px dotted red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: as you can see, I need 2 columns... did you try your solution?

Comment: Here is the implementation https://codepen.io/arvindm95/pen/PeGWwJ.
If this is not what you intended to do, explain elaborately what you want.

Comment: ah, i didn't remark the `width: 100%;` :) yes, is better now

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer.

Comment: ok, I will accept your answer, it was nice from you. But to note I did use the @Terry duplicate answer's solution for my needs.