# Word wrap avoid single words per line

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm trying to find a way to avoid headline word wraps that leaves the last word on it own line using CSS, jQuery or PHP. Example of what I want it does and what I want it to do.

From this:

```
Hello This is a Long 
Headline
```

To this:

```
Hello This is a
Long Headline
```

Comment: Interesting question. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: at what point should it be split?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about taking the white-space before the final word and replacing it with a non-breaking space?

```
<h1>Hello this is a long headline</h1>

<script>
$("h1").html(function(i, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.replace(/\s+([^\s]+)$/, "&nbsp;$1");
});
</script>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BdApF/

(For more information about passing a function to the [`.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) see the [doco](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: At least in FF 8, it looks the same with or without.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: It works in both Chrome and IE8, the only browsers I have on this computer. Note that this doesn't cause the headline to wrap, it just makes sure that _if_ it wraps you won't get the last word by itself, so to see it work you have to resize your browser. I thought that's what the question was saying to do.

Comment: Interesting, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4945298/451969) also proposes the same thing with a jQuery plugin. I initially posted this link in a comment under the answer, but then removed it thinking it was print only. But that actually does do the same thing. +1

Comment: Thanks for that @JaredFarrish - I'm not familiar with many jQuery plugins and had not heard of that one, though it didn't even occur to me to look for a plugin when I realised I could do it in one line: a plugin seems like overkill. I love the plugin name though, "Widon't".

Comment: Using a plugin is up to the developer (repeating a single line over and over may not be the best approach, for instance), or some other approach. Note, forcing the issue on display in your fiddle would probably help, as well: http://jsfiddle.net/BdApF/1/

Comment: @nnnnnn That's awesome, I didn't try anything before, I couldn't even think of what it would be called and didn't even think about a non-breaking space. What if I wanted at least 3 word on the line instead of just two?

Comment: Hi kel. I don't have time right now to think up a regex way to do three words on the line in a single step, but the simple solution is just to run the replace from my answer twice, i.e., within the function above say `return oldHtml.replace(/\s+([^\s]+)$/, "&nbsp;$1").replace(/\s+([^\s]+)$/, "&nbsp;$1");` - demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BdApF/3/